# Why do /**/ comments work in stylesheets, but // comments don't?

Tags: css, comments

Is there a good reason for this?  It is a lame question, but I just wondered if there was a reason why.

Comment: because they forgot it could be useful when they created it.

Comment: @micheal or more likely, because they realized it wasn't that useful, and would require making newlines special. The two additional characters required for /**/ is not a great burden considering the flexiblity it gives the rest of the format.

Comment: Despite the snark and "because it is" answers, this is a legitimate question. The existing syntax is quite cumbersome for inline comments, so it's reasonable to wonder if there's a rationale for not having an inline comment syntax. (And kudos to @jball for providing one.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The syntax for comments in CSS is: `/* comment here */`

The `//` is not a valid syntax. I guess this allows CSS to work correctly when stripped from [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) and [new line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters during [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).

Comment: @Daniel That seems like a really good reason for @jbail's answer above.

Comment: Wait a minute though...you can minify Javascript and it supports the // method of commenting...*scratches head*..the js minifiers remove the comments...

Comment: @leeand00 You can specify the end of line with a semi-colon though. If you have your semi colon insertion wrong, it will break when minified.

Comment: It would be surprising for CSS minification to be the rationale for a design decision that has no impact on minification whatsoever - for all purposes, comments are treated like whitespace and a minification process should remove them (or turn them to spaces) accordingly. Sure, there are IE fixes that rely on `/**/` being there, but a specific post-specification implementation bug is hardly taken into account in the pre-specification design phases ...

Answer (score 55):

Because the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments) allows for /**/ but not // :)

Seriously, though, CSS treats newlines like all other whitespace, and would not be able to determine the end of the comment without a terminating delimiter.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the rationale. I had never considered that the `//` comment in C++ was an exception to 'whitespace neutrality'

Comment: Tagalong: `//` comments in C outside of functions can cause serious compiler puke-age depending on your compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure why this prevented the use of '//' comments. Most languages provide some exception to 'whitespace neutrality' and I don't see any major downside.

Comment: @Kevin I could agree, but then I think of all the cases I've seen a xsl file end up with the entire thing on a single line.  It seems alot of tools(maybe less now that they've matured more) used to discard your whitespace/returns and spit everything out on one line.

Comment: @Aaron Good point. I forgot about the huge movement to compress all web assets.

Comment: Keep in mind that `//` comments are not an exception to whitespace neutrality. `//[^\n]*\n` **is** a whitespace in C++, and is treated as such by the lexer. I believe the actual reason is given by AaronLS - at the time when CSS was designed, the web infrastructure as a whole was not newline-friendly (as it had evolved along with newline-indifferent HTML), so reliance on the newline *character* for anything was risky at best.

Comment: @Victor Nicollet - the `//` does require an exception to whitespace neutrality, since the `\n` is treated differently than all other whitespace characters in the comment.

Answer (score 14):

Because `/* */` is the style that is defined for comments in CSS.

There are a lot of other ways to write comments in other environments that doesn't work in CSS, like:

`//`

`<!-- -->`

`--`

`'`

`REM`

`{ }`

`;`

`#`

Comment: # comments are supported in CSS (IE doesn't though). I use it when i want something in IE but not in other browsers.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: I can't see anything about # for comments in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments

Comment: @Guffa: I didn't mean it's officially documented anywhere, i was just sharing my personal experience. You can test it if you want.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Mozilla doesn't have anything about it in the documentation either. It seems that it's not something that is supported, just a difference in how incorrect code is parsed.

Comment: You are right @Guffa, it's not officially documented anywhere. It just works, maybe a bug...but a useful bug sometimes.

Comment: Regardless of the character used, many languages support single-line comments.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Re "It just works": It is undefined behaviour. Anything could happen, incl. sending an email to the moon.

Answer (score 2):

Because the CSS language is defined so.

Answer (score 2):

Different languages have different specifications with different functionality.  In [another language](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/comments.html) you may have comments that start with # instead of //.

See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/).

> 4.1.9 Comments
>
> Comments begin with the characters
>   `/*` and end with the characters `*/`.
>   They may occur anywhere between
>   tokens, and their contents have no
>   influence on the rendering. Comments
>   may not be nested.
>
> CSS also allows the SGML comment
>   delimiters (`<!--` and `-->`) in
>   certain places defined by the grammar,
>   but they do not delimit CSS comments.
>   They are permitted so that style rules
>   appearing in an HTML source document
>   (in the STYLE element) may be hidden
>   from pre-HTML 3.2 user agents. See the
>   HTML 4 specification ([HTML4]) for
>   more information.

Note: There is no mention of comments that begin with 2 slashes and end at the line break.   So that's why it's not supported.

Comment: Re *"comments that start with # instead of //."*: That would include [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), and [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you want this style of comment (and a variety of other useful features that should have been in the CSS specification), try using a [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: I would say that the possibility to use `//` as comment is not a reason to start using `LESS CSS`. But it looks like it has a lot of other useful features that would be very good reasons for using it..