# Commenting the lines in .css file

Tags: css

I need to get commented the entire class 'form-success'

How its possible?

```
    .form-success {

        background-color: #DFF0D8;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
/*      font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0.4em 0.7em;*/ 
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 8px;
        text-align:center;
        color: #468847;
}
```

Comment: What i exactly need is, it should comment starting from  the  class 'form-success'.And once i uncommented , then it should look like what it was

Comment: Ah, then you're not quite asking the right question. Sac's of using the same class name twice is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Nested Comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459988/css-nested-comments)

Answer (score 2):

as per I think what he needs is

```
.form-success {
        background-color: #DFF0D8;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
/*      font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0.4em 0.7em;*/ 
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 8px;
        text-align:center;
        color: #468847;
}
```

now comment whole class what he need is something like this which is incorrect & make problem

```
/*
.form-success {
            background-color: #DFF0D8;
            border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    /*      font-size: 1.2em;
            padding: 0.4em 0.7em;*/ 
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 8px;
            text-align:center;
            color: #468847;
    }
*/
```

I think for that you should use same class name two times...

```
.form-success {
        background-color: #DFF0D8;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 8px;
        text-align:center;
        color: #468847;
}

.form-success {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
}
```

then comment as you want...

Comment: a haaa , dirty trick ! But +1 , @Sac.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this ?

```
  /*.form-success {

    background-color: #DFF0D8;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 8px;
    text-align:center;
    color: #468847; 
                 }*/
```

Comment: No.Once i uncomment ur answer , then font-size will be active

Comment: There is no feature like this , I think !

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
/*.form-success {

background-color: #DFF0D8;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding: 0.4em 0.7em;
padding: 10px;
margin: 8px;
text-align:center;
color: #468847; 
}*/
```

Comment: What i exactly need is, it should comment starting from the class 'form-success'.And once i uncommented , then it should look like what it was

Comment: @Linto, below on another answer you state 'What i exactly need is, it should comment starting from the class 'form-success'.And once i uncommented , then it should look like what it was ' .... what you're saying is conflicting