# CSS Nested Comment Multiline Code Comment Inside Other Comment

Tags: css

Inside a CSS file I've got 2 ways to format a body element.
How can I comment to select body style 1?

```
/* body style 1 */
body {
  background-color: #E6F6F6; /* color 1 */
}

/* I want to comment all from here to end */
/*
/* body style 2 */
body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6; /* color 2 */
} /* this right bracket is not commented out */
p {
    font-size: 10px;
}
*/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Nested Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459988/css-nested-comments)

Answer (score 2):

CSS comments run until the first instance of */. You cannot nest CSS comments.

You could do something like this, but it's messy:

```
/* body style 1 */
body {
  background-color: #E6F6F6; /* color 1 */
}

/* I want to comment all from here to end */
/*
/* body style 2 */
/*body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6; /* color 2 */
/* } /* this right bracket is not commented out */
p {
    font-size: 10px;
}
*/
```

Comment: @ColinD I want to try and compare different format styles while I am developing. So do I have to keep different CSS files and copy paste?

Comment: I would, yes. I also find the Chrome dev tools to be exceptionally useful in making on-the-fly style changes.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `/*color 2*/` comment and additional comments and then it will work

```
/* body style 1 */
body {
  background-color: #E6F6F6; 
}

/* I want to comment all from here to end */

/* body style 2 */
/*
body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6; 
} 
p {
    font-size: 10px;
}
*/
```