# How can I change the color of an 'svg' element?

Tags: css, svg, colors

I want to [use this technique](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) and change the SVG color, but so far I haven't been able to do so. I use this in the CSS, but my image is always black, no matter what.

My code:

```css
.change-my-color {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <image class="change-my-color" xlink:href="https://svgur.com/i/AFM.svg" width="96" height="96" src="ppngfallback.png" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm no svg expert, but have you tried changing fill to background-color?

Comment: @Megan in svg background-color is specified with the 'fill' property and the border with 'stroke' (as you would do in Illustrator). http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html

Comment: CSS from your HTML document will not apply to SVG elements within <img />

Comment: This is possible now. Simple and functional answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/467240

Comment: Hi, you should probably change the acceepted answer (look at the most voted one).

Comment: To have any CSS abilities, you can use Font Icon. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479636/7221507

Comment: you can use this web site to filter your svg to specific color https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style SVG with external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434094/how-to-style-svg-with-external-css)

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that this question has only been revived because of ChatGPT

Comment: Just use the 'fill' attribute for the SVG Element

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You can't change the color of an image that way. If you load SVG as an image, you can't change how it is displayed using CSS or JavaScript in the browser.

If you want to change your SVG image, you have to load it using `<object>`, `<iframe>` or using `<svg>` inline.

If you want to use the techniques in the page, you need the [Modernizr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernizr) library, where you can check for SVG support and conditionally display or not a fallback image. You can then inline your SVG and apply the styles you need.

See:

```css
#time-3-icon {
   fill: green;
}

.my-svg-alternate {
  display: none;
}
.no-svg .my-svg-alternate {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

```html
<svg width="96px" height="96px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="time-3-icon" d="M256,50C142.229,50,50,142.229,50,256c0,113.77,92.229,206,206,206c113.77,0,206-92.23,206-206
    C462,142.229,369.77,50,256,50z M256,417c-88.977,0-161-72.008-161-161c0-88.979,72.008-161,161-161c88.977,0,161,72.007,161,161
    C417,344.977,344.992,417,256,417z M382.816,265.785c1.711,0.297,2.961,1.781,2.961,3.518v0.093c0,1.72-1.223,3.188-2.914,3.505
    c-37.093,6.938-124.97,21.35-134.613,21.35c-13.808,0-25-11.192-25-25c0-9.832,14.79-104.675,21.618-143.081
    c0.274-1.542,1.615-2.669,3.181-2.669h0.008c1.709,0,3.164,1.243,3.431,2.932l18.933,119.904L382.816,265.785z"/>
</svg>

<image class="my-svg-alternate" width="96" height="96" src="ppngfallback.png" />
```

You can inline your SVG. Tag your fallback image with a class name (`my-svg-alternate`):

```
<svg width="96px" height="96px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="time-3-icon" .../>
</svg>

<image class="my-svg-alternate" width="96" height="96" src="ppngfallback.png" />
```

And in CSS use the `no-svg` class from Modernizr (CDN: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.2.js ) to check for SVG support. If there isn't any SVG support, the SVG block will be ignored and the image will be displayed, otherwise the image will be removed from the DOM tree (`display: none`):

```
.my-svg-alternate {
  display: none;
}
.no-svg .my-svg-alternate {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

Then you can change the color of your inlined element:

```
#time-3-icon {
   fill: green;
}
```

Comment: You cannot style embedded `object` SVGs from the hosting document.

Comment: @JavierRey you could inject the styling into the object tag's contents via javascript. But you're right that it does not apply if you just add it to the hosting document's stylesheet.

Comment: I'm using the solution from @manish-menaria and it works perfectly.

Comment: Accepted answer should be changed to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/467240

Comment: sometimes you just need to remove the def tag inside your SVG file, because if you have it, your CSS rules will not be applied:
``
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#373435}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
``

Comment: this answer makes no sense, where is the svg image file name ??? , why use viewbox or enable background ? what if you want to change the color, and not the background ?

Comment: There is a way to do it, just give the svg fill="currentColor" property, than it will get color from CSS color assigned to it (font color). See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65147574/8230784

Comment: We can just write ```<svg style="fill: the color required">...</svg>```. Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: This was a great answer a few years ago but CSS Filter effects have totally changed the game. This answer isn't actually the correct one any longer. That makes me so happy as a web dev... progress!

Answer (score 1556):

**2020 answer**

[CSS Filter works on all current browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility)

#### To change any SVGs color

1. Add the SVG image using an `<img>` tag.

   ```html
   <img src="dotted-arrow.svg" class="filter-green"/>
   ```
2. To filter to a specific color, use the following [Codepen (click here to open the codepen)](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) to convert a hexadecimal color code to a CSS filter:

   For example, output for `#00EE00` is

   ```css
   filter: invert(42%) sepia(93%) saturate(1352%) hue-rotate(87deg) brightness(119%) contrast(119%);
   ```

   Generate a `filter` for any color [here](https://isotropic.co/hex-color-to-css-filter).
3. Add the CSS `filter` into this class.

   ```css
   .filter-green{
       filter: invert(48%) sepia(79%) saturate(2476%) hue-rotate(86deg) brightness(118%) contrast(119%);
   }
   ```

Comment: This comes with the usual caveat about not being supported in older browser versions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: As noted in the CodePen, if your SVG isn't black (mine was grey), adding `brightness(0) saturate(100%)` to the beginning of the list of filters will first turn it 100% black, which enables the other filters to change it to the correct color.

Comment: Also, lots of fascinating background on the solution in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters/43960991#43960991) that informed the CodePen.

Comment: My guy. The support seems acceptable https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters.

Comment: works so well, used this unaffiliated codepen to get my hex into a filter: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: but how do you specify a particular color ?

Comment: This is great! I dynamically change the color of an SVG in a React app using the npm package [hex-to-css-filter](https://github.com/willmendesneto/hex-to-css-filter#usage)

Comment: Pressing the button in the link provided seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: from a black svg, you can get the "filter values" for any color with the following tool: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: We can just write ```<svg style="fill: the color required">...</svg>```. Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Should mention how to calculate this for any color: https://isotropic.co/hex-color-to-css-filter/

Comment: Any ways to apply a filter to an image used as the background of an element?

Comment: What makes a thousand ones think this is better than leave it as <svg> and apply CSS fill:color into it?

Comment: I don't recommend using `filter` to invert colors in an image [because that will create a new stacking-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764404/why-does-stacking-order-change-on-webkit-filter-hover) (which messes-up `position`ed elements and z-indexing). When I need to invert colors or similar I just create a second separate image, though I appreciate this doesn't work for dynamically-generated or user-supplied images.

Comment: Duplicate of that earlier answer, should have been an edit instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49049008/3795597

Comment: Seems to be working well with .png images as well. Sick!

Comment: I wish I could just pass a CSS color name for this

Comment: This approach worked to change the entire svg to a single color. I'm curious if there's a way to apply one filter to the "fill" and another filter to the "stroke" (I think that's the svg term for the lines/outlines"?

Comment: And how do I achieve a gradient instead of a single color?

Comment: Wow! Couldn't be any more cryptic than that! Whatever happend to a simple: `filter: #ff0000`?

Comment: Thanks! I tried a lot of solutions but this was the only one that worked reliably (without inlining or manually editing multiple svg files). Honestly I'm very surprised that it's 2023 and something as simple as changing an svg color dynamically is so unintuitive and complicated.

Comment: I had some issues with the provided filter generator. This one seemed more accurate: https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/

Comment: If you want to just use a hex color to colorize a non-inline SVG, see the answer below that mentions "CSS Mask Property"

Answer (score 555):

To change the color of any SVG, you can directly change the SVG code by **opening the SVG file in any text editor**. The code may look like the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">

    <g>
        <path d="M114.26,436.584L99.023,483h301.953l-15.237-46.416H114.26z M161.629,474.404h-49.592l9.594-29.225h69.223
                 C181.113,454.921,171.371,464.663,161.629,474.404z"/>

    /* Some more code goes on */
    </g>
</svg>
```

You can observe that there are some XML tags like path, circle, polygon, etc.. There you can add your own color with help of the style attribute. Look at the below example

```
<path fill="#AB7C94" d="M114.26,436.584L99.023,483h301.953l-15.237-46.416H114.26z M161.629,474.404h-49.592l9.594-29.225h69.223
                        C181.113,454.921,171.371,464.663,161.629,474.404z"/>
```

Add the style attribute to all the tags so that you can get your SVG of your required color.

As per Daniel's comment, we can use fill attribute directly instead of fill element inside style attribute.

Comment: Why not just using attribute `fill` like this: `fill = "#AB7C94"` ? Not sure why the `style` attribute is needed

Comment: Hi Daniel, yeah it works. I didn't knew that fill can be used as an attribute. Sorry for not noticing your comment so long @bg17aw

Comment: This should be the best answer because it provides the same result which much less code. Less code, better code.

Comment: If you don't want to change the color of the svg programmatically, this is the best and easiest solution. Thank you!

Comment: as note, this method change the source file (base color), if you need change the color dynamically, you can use the css code like the `Manish Menaria` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/8979042)..

Comment: Problem I see is, if we need may different colors. Its will increase the size of project & slower the page loading. But SVG's are normally small in size. In my case its not a problem to add few images. But this is a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: Use the color attribute to change the color of an SVG element: `color="#ffffff"`, fill will just fill out the SVG with color, not change the color.

Answer (score 495):

If you want to change the color dynamically:

1. Open the SVG in a code editor
2. Add or rewrite the attribute of `fill` of every **path** to `fill="currentColor"`
3. Now, that svg will take the color of your font color, so you can do something like:

   ```css
   svg {
       color : "red";
   }
   ```

Comment: This is how icons (SVGs) from font-awesome do it. Works great.

Comment: Also you may have to change `stroke` attributes to `stroke="currentColor"`.

Comment: This is the way. Coupled with a SVGO plugin that automatically translates all SVG files, it's a great solution! See gist: https://gist.github.com/joakimriedel/b001b5bedd70274adcb6238b267565d8

Comment: It doesn't work if SVG is saved as a file and displayed with `<img>` tag.

Comment: How are you including the SVG, inline or using an img tag? Please include in your answer.

Comment: Should add that it only works if you are using the svg inline in the html.

Comment: changing manually fill attribute works -> stroke="currentColor"., I'm working with Angular Material, adding a custon icon a then changing color via html.

Comment: this works when icons is displayed as element and not as image , 
usage example:
<myIcon id="colored-title" />
#colored-title{color:"red"}

Comment: For anyone using JS to create their html: setting an svg's outerHTML to "<svg...</svg>" as a string will insert a proper svg tag into the html, that will work with this answer

Comment: best way to do it.... consider if you have to deal with :hover :focus etc ... Thank You

Answer (score 111):

**Only SVG with path information**. You can't do that to the image... as the path you can change stroke and fill information and you are done. *like [Adobe Illustrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator)*

So, via CSS you can overwrite the path `fill` value:

```css
path { fill: orange; }
```

But if you want a more flexible way as you want to change it with a text when having some hovering effect going on, use:

```css
path { fill: currentColor; }
```

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.parent {
  width: 320px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/***  desired colors for children  ***/
.parent{
  color: #000;
  background: #def;
}
.parent:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background: #85c1fc;
}

.parent span{
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  line-height: 26px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.parent svg{
  max-height: 26px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
}

/****  magic trick  *****/
.parent svg path{
  fill: currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <span>TEXT WITH SVG</span>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a great and awesome solution in a simple way, I've tried the way, and it's working for me. Thank you.

Comment: yes, I know now, use the `fill` in `path` of SVG, not in `svg` itself. thankyou!

Answer (score 72):

### Solution 1 - Edit SVG to point to the currentColor

```html
<svg>... fill: currentColor stroke: currentColor ...</svg>
```

Then you can control the color of the stroke and the fill from your CSS content:

```css
svg {
  color: blue; /* Or any color of your choice. */
}
```

Pros and cons:

- Simple and uses conventional supported CSS.

Suitable if:

- You control the SVG
- SVG can be included inline in the HTML.

### Solution 2 - CSS mask property

```html
<i class="icon"></i>
```

```css
  .icon {
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    mask-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(https://url.of.svg/....svg);
    mask-image: url(https://url.of.svg/....svg);
    background-color: blue; /* Or any color of your choice. */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }

}
```

Pros and cons

- Relatively easy to use
- Browser support for the `mask` CSS property is partial.

Suitable if:

- SVG is external, and included via URL
- Meant to be used on modern known browsers.

### Solution 3 - CSS Filter property - static color

If the color is known in advance, you can use https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp to find the filter needed to change your SVG to the desired color. For example, to convert the svg to `#00f`:

```html
<img src="https://url.of.svg/....svg" class="icon">
```

```css
.icon {
    filter: invert(8%) sepia(100%) saturate(6481%) hue-rotate(246deg) brightness(102%) contrast(143%);
}
```

If your original color isn't black, prefix the list of filters with `brightness(0) saturate(100%)` to convert it first to black.

Pros and cons:

- There might be a small, nonsignificant difference between the result and the desired color.

Suitable if:

- Desired color is known in advance.
- External image

Comment: On Solution 3 pros and cons; it might be worth adding that using multiple filters on complex SVG images have a huge negative impact on performance. And should be used sparingly if at all.

Comment: The C style `/* */` [is the ***only*** valid comment character sequence in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479351/why-do-comments-work-in-stylesheets-but-comments-dont). Otherwise, the consequence is likely silently ignored CSS content. [A CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) will report an error: "`7 Parse Error // Or any color of your choice. width: 20px`"

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen !! 
That's what happens when you edit your code on Stackoverflow instead of the code editor ...

Comment: How can I like this multiple times! This was it. If the original color isn't black you really need to first convert to black by prefixing with 'brightness(0) saturate(100%)'  Was really helpful

Answer (score 58):

I added a test page - to color SVG via Filter settings:

For example,

`filter: invert(0.5) sepia(1) saturate(5) hue-rotate(175deg)`

[Upload & Color your SVG - Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tw2gjwt/52/)

I took the idea from: *[Swapping Fill Color on Image Tag SVGs](https://blog.union.io/code/2017/08/10/img-svg-fill/)*

Comment: Thanks, you just save me from myself. `.custom-disabled > svg {filter:invert(0.2) sepia(1) saturte(0) hue-rotate(0);}` did just the job I need to disabled icon.

Comment: This answer helped me to change the color for image on hover and to convert the hex color to CSS filter I found following online hex-color to CSS filter converters.
https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/
https://isotropic.co/tool/hex-color-to-css-filter/

Answer (score 34):

### SVG [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) on a box element with a *background color* will result:

```css
body{ overflow:hidden; }

.icon {
  --size: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  transition: .12s;
  
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-size: cover;
}

.icon-bike {
  background: black;
  animation: 4s frames infinite linear;
  
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/89/89139.svg);
  mask-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/89/89139.svg);
}

@keyframes frames {
  0% { transform:translatex(100vw) }
  25% { background: red; }
  75% { background: lime; }
  100% { transform:translatex(-100%) }
}
```

```html
<i class="icon icon-bike" style="--size:150px"></i>
```

---

<sub>Note - SVG masks are not supported in *Internet Explorer* browsers</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vsync this is just the best hack around for what I need.

Comment: This is great. However with this approach, we use the img alt field, for accessibility. Any idea on how to bring that back? Thanks!

Comment: @Will59 - use the [ARIA rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/img_role):  `<i role="img" aria-label="Description">`

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way would be to create a font out of the SVG using a service like https://icomoon.io/app/#/select or such. Upload your SVG, click "generate font", include font files and CSS content into your side and just use and style it like any other text. I always use it like this because it makes styling much easier.

But as mentioned in [the article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xXBYcWgCHA) commented by @CodeMouse92, icon fonts mess up screen readers (and are possibly bad for SEO). So rather stick to the SVGs.

Comment: It also messes up screen readers. See ["Death to Icon Fonts" by Seren Davies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xXBYcWgCHA)

Comment: Icon fonts are not bad for SEO. Not understanding how SEO works is what is bad for SEO. Learn about Section 508, ADA, and WCAG, and then you'll understand how to use font icons even better based on do's and don'ts. The video you referenced has been viewed 8500 times with 111 likes. You take this as religion?

Answer (score 14):

To simply change the color of the SVG file:

Go to the SVG file and under styles, mention the color in fill:

```
<style>.cls-1{fill: #FFFFFF;}</style>
```

Comment: Already suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27287453/1038015)

Answer (score 14):

You can try to color it with this css filter hack:

```
.colorize-pink {
  filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(-70deg) saturate(5);
}

.colorize-navy {
  filter: brightness(0.2) sepia(1) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(5);
}

.colorize-blue {
  filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(140deg) saturate(6);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

To change the color of an SVG element, I have found out a way while inspecting the Google search box search icon below:

```css
.search_icon {
  color: red;
  fill: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="search_icon">
    <svg focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path></svg>
</span>
```

I have used a *[span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span)* element with "display:inline-block", height, width and setting a particular style "color: red; **fill: currentColor;**" to that span tag which is inherited by the child *svg* element.

Comment: This was the best answer. Wrapping the svg in a span or div and applying ```fill: currentColor;``` to it is the key.

Comment: Can't believe no one else mentioned this. This is THE answer.

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't need to be wrapped in a `span`, almost any element works as a wrapper.

Answer (score 13):

Target the path within the 'svg' tag:

```
<svg>
   <path>....
</svg>
```

You can do it inline, like:

```
<path fill="#ccc">
```

Or

```
svg{
   path{
        fill: #ccc
```

Answer (score 12):

You can change SVG coloring with CSS if you use some tricks.
I wrote a small script for that.

- go through a list of elements which do have an SVG image
- load the SVG file as XML
- fetch only the SVG part
- change color of path
- replace src with the modified SVG image as an inline image

```js
$('img.svg-changeable').each(function () {
  var $e = $(this);
  var imgURL = $e.prop('src');

  $.get(imgURL, function (data) {
    // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
    var $svg = $(data).find('svg');

    // Change the color
    $svg.find('path').attr('fill', '#000');

    $e.prop('src', "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa($svg.prop('outerHTML')));
  });

});
```

The code above might not be working correctly. I've implemented this for elements with an SVG background image which works nearly similar to this.

But anyway, you have to modify this script to fit your case.

Comment: By the way: If you are a RoR developer, you can add a new method for the sass precompiler which can do the job too. This is much better because you will have the base64 encoded, correct colored image in your compiled css file. No JS needed anymore! Maybe I could provide the code I have written, have to talk to the CTO.

Comment: +1 for providing a solution, rather than saying it can't be done. This answer is also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Answer (score 11):

1. Method 1

   The easy and effect way:

   Open your .svg file with any text editor

   ```
   <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 477.526 477.526" style="enable-background:new 0 0 477.526 477.526;
      fill: rgb(109, 248, 248);" xml:space="preserve">
   <svg />
   ```

   Give an style attribute and fill that with color.
2. Another way

   Fill with color in your shape. Here i have **rect** shape `fill="white"`.

   ```
   <svg width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <g>
           <title>background</title>
           <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="602" width="802" y="-1"
            x="-1"/>

               <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"
                  id="canvasGrid">

                  <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%"
                  width="100%"/>
               </g>
       </g>
   </svg>
   ```

Answer (score 11):

## 2022 Web Component `<load-file>` answer

This (7 line) **native Web Component** (JSWC) loads *external* content, and **injects** it into the DOM.

It is explained and documented in my [DEV blog post: *<load-file> Web Component*](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd).

**Full source code:**

```js
customElements.define("load-file", class extends HTMLElement {

  // declare default connectedCallback as sync so await can be used
  async connectedCallback(
      // call connectedCallback with parameter to *replace* SVG (of <load-file> persists)
      src = this.getAttribute("src"),
    // attach a shadowRoot if none exists (prevents displaying error when moving Nodes)
    // declare as parameter to save 4 Bytes: 'let '
    shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
  ) {
      // load SVG file from src="" async, parse to text, add to shadowRoot.innerHTML
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(src)).text()

    // append optional <tag [shadowRoot]> Elements from inside <load-svg> after parsed <svg>
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"))

    // if "replaceWith" attribute
    // then replace <load-svg> with loaded content <load-svg>
    // childNodes instead of children to include #textNodes also
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
})
```

```html
<load-file src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
  <!-- elements inside load-file are MOVED to shadowDOM -->
  <style shadowRoot>
    svg {
      height: 180px; /* Stack Overflow subwindow height */
    }
    path:nth-child(2n+2) {
      fill: GREEN; /* shadowDOM style does NOT style global DOM */
    }
  </style>
</load-file>
```

Comment: Wow this is quick, easy and has zero implementation problems (in comparison to other solutions, given my project characteristics).

Comment: You should probably disclose that it is your own blog post. See e.g. *[Why am I getting push-back for linking to my own blog posts in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278505)*, *[What is the policy for linking to your own blog in your answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254280/)*, and *[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/)*.

Answer (score 8):

Here the fast and furious way :)

```css
body {
    background-color: #DEFF05;
}

svg {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}

svg path {
    color: red;
    fill: currentcolor;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 514.666 514.666"><path d="M514.666,210.489L257.333,99.353L0,210.489l45.933,19.837v123.939h30V243.282l33.052,14.274v107.678l4.807,4.453  c2.011,1.862,50.328,45.625,143.542,45.625c93.213,0,141.53-43.763,143.541-45.626l4.807-4.452V257.557L514.666,210.489z   M257.333,132.031L439,210.489l-181.667,78.458L75.666,210.489L257.333,132.031z M375.681,351.432  c-13.205,9.572-53.167,33.881-118.348,33.881c-65.23,0-105.203-24.345-118.348-33.875v-80.925l118.348,51.112l118.348-51.111  V351.432z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: why vote down !? this work well you can see it in the demo

Comment: Your answer explains nothing in contrast with others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720935/3795597 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419873/3795597 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69397734/3795597 and countless others. It only works because you embed the svg in the main document.

Answer (score 7):

If the same SVG must be used multiple times with different colors, define the set of paths within a hidden SVG which serves as the master copy. Then place new instances which refer to the master path with their individual fills.

Note: This approach only works with inline `<svg>` tags. It will not work with `<img>` tags loading `.svg` files.

```css
:root {
  fill: gray;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

svg {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="hidden">
 <path id="s_fave" d="m379 21c-57 0-104 53-123 78-19-25-66-78-123-78-74 0-133 68-133 151 0 45 18 88 49 116 0.5 0.8 1 2 2 2l197 197c2 2 5 3 8 3s5-1 8-3l206-206c2-2 3-3 5-5 0.8-0.8 1-2 2-3 23-28 35-64 35-102 0-83-60-151-133-151z"/>
 <path id="s_star" d="m511 196c-3-10-13-18-23-19l-148-13-58-137c-4-10-14-17-25-17-11 0-21 6-25 17l-58 137-148 13c-11 1-20 8-23 19-3 10-0.3 22 8 29l112 98-33 145c-2 11 2 22 11 28 5 3 10 5 16 5 5 0 10-1 14-4l127-76 127 76c9 6 21 5 30-1 9-6 13-17 11-28l-33-145 112-98c8-7 11-19 8-29z"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_fave"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_star"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_fave" fill="red"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_star" fill="gold"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_fave" fill="purple"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_star" fill="silver"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_fave" fill="pink"></use></svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#s_star" fill="blue"></use></svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

For example, in your HTML:

```html
<body>
  <svg viewBox="" width="" height="">
    <path id="struct1" fill="#xxxxxx" d="M203.3,71.6c-.........."></path>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Use jQuery:

```
$("#struct1").css("fill", "<desired colour>");
```

Comment: This only works if you include the SVG file inline in the HTML. I've edited your answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this code. It works.

```html
<div>
   <!-- YouTube -->
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
       <path fill="white"
           d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z" />
   </svg>

   <!-- Instagram -->
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
       <path fill="white"
           d="M224.1 141c-63.6 0-114.9 51.3-114.9 114.9s51.3 114.9 114.9 114.9S339 319.5 339 255.9 287.7 141 224.1 141zm0 189.6c-41.1 0-74.7-33.5-74.7-74.7s33.5-74.7 74.7-74.7 74.7 33.5 74.7 74.7-33.6 74.7-74.7 74.7zm146.4-194.3c0 14.9-12 26.8-26.8 26.8-14.9 0-26.8-12-26.8-26.8s12-26.8 26.8-26.8 26.8 12 26.8 26.8zm76.1 27.2c-1.7-35.9-9.9-67.7-36.2-93.9-26.2-26.2-58-34.4-93.9-36.2-37-2.1-147.9-2.1-184.9 0-35.8 1.7-67.6 9.9-93.9 36.1s-34.4 58-36.2 93.9c-2.1 37-2.1 147.9 0 184.9 1.7 35.9 9.9 67.7 36.2 93.9s58 34.4 93.9 36.2c37 2.1 147.9 2.1 184.9 0 35.9-1.7 67.7-9.9 93.9-36.2 26.2-26.2 34.4-58 36.2-93.9 2.1-37 2.1-147.8 0-184.8zM398.8 388c-7.8 19.6-22.9 34.7-42.6 42.6-29.5 11.7-99.5 9-132.1 9s-102.7 2.6-132.1-9c-19.6-7.8-34.7-22.9-42.6-42.6-11.7-29.5-9-99.5-9-132.1s-2.6-102.7 9-132.1c7.8-19.6 22.9-34.7 42.6-42.6 29.5-11.7 99.5-9 132.1-9s102.7-2.6 132.1 9c19.6 7.8 34.7 22.9 42.6 42.6 11.7 29.5 9 99.5 9 132.1s2.7 102.7-9 132.1z" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
svg {
   fill: white;
}
```

Comment: Why is the CSS part syntax highlighted like that?

Answer (score 5):

I found it a bit clumsy, but it is definitely a working way to **dynamically** change the color of an SVG **included with `<img>` tag**.

In the SVG file, you can add CSS content the following way:

```xml
<svg ...>
    <defs>
        <style>
            ...
        <style>
    <defs>
```

There you can use **@media** rules, with which the SVG can look outside itself for contextual circumstances. There's an **aspect-ratio** media feature that applies to the SVG box (e.g., the `<img>` tag). You can create different contexts for the SVG by stretching the SVG box a little bit.

This way you can also make the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) the same SVG that appears on the website, but with a different color. (In this case, no other SVG boxes should be square-shaped.)

```css
/* img stretched horizontally (if SVG is square-shaped) */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1000/999) {
    path {
        fill: blue;
    }
}

/* img stretched vertically (if SVG is square-shaped) */
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 999/1000) {
    path {
        fill: green;
    }
}

/* img with exact sizes */
@media (aspect-ratio: 86/74) {
    path {
        fill: red;
    }
}

/* favicon with light browser theme */
@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    path {
        fill: black;
    }
}

/* favicon with dark browser theme */
@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    path {
        fill: white;
    }
}
```

#### One very important thing

The SVG must contain viewBox information, so that the stretching does not affect the graphics. Example:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this to an inline SVG file, that is, for example, a background image in your CSS content:

```css
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='rgba(31,159,215,1)' viewBox='...'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Of course, replace the ... with your inline image code.

Answer (score 4):

Use an svg `<mask>` element.

This is better than other solutions because:

- Closely matches your original code.
- Works in IE!
- The embedded image can still be an external, unmodified file.
- The image does not even have to be an SVG.
- Color is inherited from font-color, so easy to use alongside text.
- Color is a normal CSS color, not a strange combination of filters.

```html
<svg style="color: green; width: 96px; height: 96px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <mask id="fillMask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="https://svgur.com/i/AFM.svg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" src="ppngfallback.png" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="stroke: none; fill: currentColor" mask="url(&quot;#fillMask&quot;)" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jamiegl/5jaL0s1t/19/

Comment: Works great! Note to add: the svg should be white.

Comment: This is the only answer I can get working with :hover and transitions.

Answer (score 4):

For a better resolution [about Manish Menaria's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element/53336754#53336754) (thank you so much for your help) response, use this filter generator instead a purposed generator: https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/

```css
.filter-green{
    filter: invert(48%) sepia(79%) saturate(2476%) hue-rotate(86deg) brightness(118%) contrast(119%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with [Manish Menaria's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element/53336754#53336754), if we convert white color it shows gray.

So I added some tweaks, and the below example specifically shows how to change the color in the material icon:

```html
<mat-icon class="draft-white" svgIcon="draft" aria-hidden="false"></mat-icon>
```

```css
.draft-white{
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a single-colour SVG with varying opacities that you simply want to tint to a different colour then there is another approach that can be used: the [`feFlood` SVG filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feFlood).

This solution is not as straightforward as a single-line CSS, however:

- It works on SVGs inside of an `img` element.
- This doesn't require editing the source SVG at all.
- It allows you to simply choose a target colour for the SVG and not worry about complex colour transforms, like `hue-rotate`.

Here is an example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="recolourFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feFlood flood-color="aquamarine" result="flood" />
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img style="filter: url(#recolourFilter);" width="300" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg" />
```

In the above example, we create an inline SVG to define the filters and then we apply it to the image. Inside of the `<filter>` block we first define the fill colour that we want via `<feFlood>` and then we create a composite image using the alpha channel of the source plus the flood colour. Finally, the filter is applied to the whole image via the `filter` CSS property on the `img` element.

I learned about this technique from [this Smashing Magasine article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/why-the-svg-filter-is-awesome/). It's a highly recommended read if you want to learn more about SVG filters.

A few additional things to note:

- This filter can be applied to any HTML element via the CSS `filter` property.
- The same filter can be reused multiple times on the same page.
- If you are using an inline SVG then the `<defs>` block can form part of the `svg` element and the filter can still be applied to the whole SVG or on selective elements. This avoids needing a separate SVG element for the filters.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be this. But I’m not 100% sure if it works for everyone:

Select 'svg' and then 'path'. And you can change 'fill' then.

```
.eye-icon-container {
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    :hover {
      background-color: #ddf0ff;
    }
    :active {
      background-color: #1d398d;
      svg {
        path {
          fill: #fff;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **svg** with **path** then give fill color to path:

```
    svg path{
fill:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a quite more flexible solution to this problem: writing a [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) which will patch SVG as text at runtime. I also published in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/b6663eba3257e0df2e56f140885aba23) with a link to JSFiddle.

> filter: invert(42%) sepia(93%) saturate(1352%) hue-rotate(87deg) brightness(119%) contrast(119%);

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>SVG with color</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    (function () {
      const createSvg = (color = '#ff9933') => `
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="76px" height="22px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 76 22">
            <defs/>
              <g>
                <ellipse cx="5" cy="10" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#ff9933" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"/>
                <ellipse cx="70" cy="10" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#ff9933" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"/>
                <path d="M 9.47 12.24 L 17.24 16.12 Q 25 20 30 13 L 32.5 9.5 Q 35 6 40 9 L 42.5 10.5 Q 45 12 50 6 L 52.5 3 Q 55 0 60.73 3.23 L 66.46 6.46" fill="none" stroke="#ff9933" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/>
              </g>
          </svg>`.split('#ff9933').join(color);

      function SvgWithColor() {
        const div = Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], SvgWithColor);
        const color = div.hasAttribute('color') ? div.getAttribute('color') : 'cyan';
        div.innerHTML = createSvg(color);
        return div;
      }

      SvgWithColor.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
      customElements.define('svg-with-color', SvgWithColor);

      document.body.innerHTML += `<svg-with-color
        color='magenta'
      ></svg-with-color>`;

    })();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use a font icon to use any CSS option in SVG**

I was searching for a way to have any CSS options, like animation for SVG, and I ended up generating a font icon with my SVG(s) and then using it inside a *[span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span)* (like [Font Awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome)), so any CSS option, like coloring, was available on it.

I used https://icomoon.io to convert my SVG image to a font icon. Then you can use it like Font Awesome or MaterialIcon inside HTML elements.

Comment: What is "MaterialIcon"? Do you mean Google's [Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons)? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes I mean Google material icons library

Answer (score 2):

This took a while for me to workout, you can't change the colour of an imported svg (easily), how i managed to do and keep themes / colours from `createStyles` in my react application is like so:

```
<MURadio
  icon={
    <svg
      width="24px"
      height="24px"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      style={{
        fillRule: "evenodd",
        clipRule: "evenodd",
        strokeLinejoin: "round",
        strokeMiterlimit: "2",
      }}
    >
      <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-511.714,-525.038)">
        <g transform="matrix(1.04348,0,0,1.04348,511.192,523.902)">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12.589" r="11.5" style={{ fill: "white" }} />
          <path
            d="M12,1.089C18.347,1.089 23.5,6.242 23.5,12.589C23.5,18.936 18.347,24.089 12,24.089C5.653,24.089 0.5,18.936 0.5,12.589C0.5,6.242 5.653,1.089 12,1.089ZM12,2.089C6.205,2.089 1.5,6.794 1.5,12.589C1.5,18.384 6.205,23.089 12,23.089C17.795,23.089 22.5,18.384 22.5,12.589C22.5,6.794 17.795,2.089 12,2.089Z"
            className={classes.icon}
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  }
/>;
```

```
const useRadioButtonClasses = makeStyles<ITheme, IRadioButtonErrorProps>(
  (theme) =>
    createStyles({
      radio: { color: theme.mvf.palette.border },
      card: {
        height: '100%',
      },
      icon: ({ isError }) => ({
        fill: theme.mvf.palette.border,
        ...(isError && {
          fill: theme.mvf.palette.error,
        }),
      }),
      selectedRadioIcon: ({ isError }) => ({
        fill: theme.mvf.palette.primary.main,
        ...(isError && {
          fill: theme.mvf.palette.error,
        }),
      }),
...etc
```

I am assuming some level of knowledge, as this isn't full code, but `MURadio` is an v4 material ui radio button in use in our app, with the custom `svg` in one of the props by this material ui component - so you have change the default radio icon... and you can apply a theme colour to the custom radio icon (svg) dynamically, and as i am passing `isError` state like so  `const classes = useRadioButtonClasses({ isError });` so we can change the svg colour if there is an error.

Works for me and same setup (class.icon) as we style the regular components, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is to use a mixin to control stroke colour and fill colour. My 'svg's are used as icons.

```
@mixin icon($color, $hoverColor) {
    svg {
        fill: $color;

        circle, line, path {
            fill: $color
        }

        &:hover {
            fill: $hoverColor;

            circle, line, path {
                fill: $hoverColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then do the following in your [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) file:

```
.container {
    @include icon(white, blue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) users, the **"inline-svg-2"** npm library was quite useful:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg-2
- Replace `<img src="">` with `<div inlineSVG="path_to_assets"></div>`
- set CSS "color:" in screen's SCSS file
- use **fill="currentColor"** or **stroke="currentColor"** in your SVG pictures.

You can now dynamically configure your CSS colors, including with CSS variables, and the SVG will adapt.

*Note*: The "currentColor" trick works only for inlined SVGs, this is why we need a special module for this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem using SVG elements with path as child in Styled-Component, selecting the child solve my problem with dynamic colors:

```
import { styled, css } from 'styled-component';

export const Icon = styled.svg(({ theme }) => {
  const {
    colorsValues,
  } = theme.myCustomizationObj;

  return css`
    // select the path under "svg" element
    & path {
      fill: ${colorsValue};
    }
  `;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Reactjs project. You can use the below approach.

```
import React from 'react';

type PropsType = {
  colorprimary: string;
  onClick: () => void;
  className: string;
  height?: string;
  width?: string;
};

const HamburgerIcon: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {
  const { colorprimary } = props;

  return (
    <svg viewBox='0 0 19 15' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' {...props}>
      <g id='Group 2603'>
        <path
          id='Path 2244'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          clipRule='evenodd'
          d='M0.451172 1.49133H18.3634V0H0.451172V1.49133Z'
          fill={colorprimary}
        />
        <path
          id='Path 2245'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          clipRule='evenodd'
          d='M0.451172 8.20227H18.3634V6.71094H0.451172V8.20227Z'
          fill={colorprimary}
        />
        <path
          id='Path 2246'
          fillRule='evenodd'
          clipRule='evenodd'
          d='M0.451172 14.9132H18.3634V13.4219H0.451172V14.9132Z'
          fill={colorprimary}
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

HamburgerIcon.defaultProps = {
  width: '25',
  height: '20',
};
export default HamburgerIcon;
```

Ignore types if you are not using typescript. Above solution provide more customisation to SVG, even you can add more props to make it more customisable.

here are the benefits of the provided approach:

1. Reusability: You can use the SVG icon component throughout your
   application.
2. Customization: Easily change the icon's color, width, and height using props.
3. Maintainability: Centralized location for icon code
   simplifies updates.
4. Consistency: Ensures a uniform appearance for all instances of the icon.
5. Scalability: Manage numerous icons neatly as separate components.
6. Readability: Improved code readability compared to inline SVG

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Inkscape works really well. Unless you need an SVG in several colors, just make on in the color you need and use it.

After loading the image, select each path, change the color, save as a new SVG image.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that I think solves this problem, even though it doesn't use an <img> tag, it does allow referring to a single .svg file in multiple places allowing for different colors to be directly applied using hex codes. I felt this was the right place to put my answer since this is one of the first results when searching for changing the color of an SVG, and finding this solution is quite difficult.

The first step is to make sure your SVG is formatted correctly with dimensions and viewBox as you expect it to be. I was puzzled by the viewBox in the exported SVG having different dimensions until I set the Scale value to 1 making the exported SVG 16x16 like the Inkscape SVG I'd been working on.

[image: Set document properties correctly]

Next, build your icons if you haven't already. You can put them all next to each other on the page, but this requires repositioning later when referencing them in HTML. I prefer to put all my icons together on the same 16x16 page. You can hide the ones you're not working on on the "layers" tab. Either group all parts of an icon, or combine them using "union" to give it a label and an id. Note that "menu" is a group of 3 paths and "close" is a single path. Either way will work. ("grid" is a guide I use to design the icons and is removed from the final file).

[image: Organise your icons in the layers tab]

Right-click on the icon in the layers tab, whether it's a group or a single path, and go to Object Properties. There you can give it a label and ID.

[image: Ensure each icon has an id]

Now export it as a Plain SVG and put it in your chosen location. It will require one further modification in a text editor to replace all fill and stroke colors with "currentColor."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
    width="16"
    height="16"
    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
    version="1.1"
    id="svg19528"
    xml:space="preserve"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs id="defs19525" />
<g id="layer1">
    <g
            id="menu"
            style="display:inline">
        <path
                style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:currentColor;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:fill markers stroke"
                d="M 3,3 H 13"
                id="path20582" />
        <path
                style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:currentColor;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:fill markers stroke"
                d="M 3,8 H 13"
                id="path20584" />
        <path
                style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:currentColor;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:fill markers stroke"
                d="M 3,13 H 13"
                id="path20586" />
    </g>
    <path
            id="close"
            style="color:currentColor;display:inline;fill:currentColor;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;-inkscape-stroke:none;paint-order:fill markers stroke"
            d="m 3,2 a 1,1 0 0 0 -0.7070312,0.2929688 1,1 0 0 0 0,1.4140624 L 6.5859375,8 2.2929688,12.292969 a 1,1 0 0 0 0,1.414062 1,1 0 0 0 1.4140624,0 L 8,9.4140625 12.292969,13.707031 a 1,1 0 0 0 1.414062,0 1,1 0 0 0 0,-1.414062 L 9.4140625,8 13.707031,3.7070312 a 1,1 0 0 0 0,-1.4140624 A 1,1 0 0 0 13,2 1,1 0 0 0 12.292969,2.2929688 L 8,6.5859375 3.7070312,2.2929688 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,2 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Now the SVG can be added in HTML with a <use> tag. The icon can be repositioned if it is not at the top-left of the SVG by setting the x and y attributes of the <use> tag:

```
<svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use class="my-icon"
             xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#menu"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <use class="my-other-icon"
             xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#close"></use>
    </svg>
```

Styles can be added in CSS like this:

```
.my-icon {
    color: #fe8721ff;
}
.my-other-icon {
    color: #1278efff;
}
```

This way, the .svg file is only sent to the client once and all icons are loaded from it, allowing it to set different sizes and colors easily.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add fill:"desiredColor" in the svg tag of the image:
example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#bbb9c6">
<path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L2 22l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-2 12H6v-2h12v2zm0-3H6V9h12v2zm0-3H6V6h12v2z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
```

Comment: That's basically the same suggestion as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098855/1038015) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27287453/1038015)

Comment: those answers have mentioned fill in the path tag, it worked for me in the svg tag, hence i posted it

Answer (score -1):

**Works in Chrome** last checked on August 2023

Just add a div with a class

```
<div class="icon"></div>
```

Then add this style to it

```
    .icon {
    -webkit-mask: url(SVG.svg);/*Your SVG file here*/
    mask: url(SVG.svg) ;
    background-color: blue; /* Or any color of your choice. */
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 200px !important;
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Open your image using a browser,  right-click on the image click on view page source and you will see the svg tag of the image. Cope and paste into your html, then change the fill to the colour of your choice

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253046/1038015) already suggests inlining and then setting the colour as the solution.

Answer (score -2):

You shall not set the color directly on the SVG image, if you want to program the color of the SVG.

In 2021, you can use the following CSS content to make the color change.

```css
html {
  --iron-icon-fill-color-1: green;
  --iron-icon-fill-color-2: red;
  --iron-icon-stroke-color: white;
}


svg#icon-green {
  fill: var(--iron-icon-fill-color-1, currentcolor);
  stroke: var(--iron-icon-stroke-color, none);
}

svg#icon-red {
  fill: var(--iron-icon-fill-color-2, currentcolor);
  stroke: var(--iron-icon-stroke-color, none);
}

svg#icon {
  fill: var(--iron-icon-fill-color-x, currentcolor);
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<svg id="icon-green" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40px" height="40px" style="vertical-align:text-bottom" viewbox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="18" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="M 10,10 30,30 M 10,30 30,10" fill="none"  stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>


<svg id="icon-red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40px" height="40px" style="vertical-align:text-bottom" viewbox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="18" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="M 10,10 30,30 M 10,30 30,10" fill="none"  stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>

<svg id="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40px" height="40px" style="vertical-align:text-bottom" viewbox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="18" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="M 10,10 30,30 M 10,30 30,10" fill="none"  stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You do not explain why. What you are doing is simply inlining the svg to be part of the main DOM.

Comment: Why is the syntax highlighting so weird for the CSS part? It seems to be marked up correctly.

Answer (score -2):

My usage is with [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) icons, copying your SVG path.

```
span{
    path{
        color: red;
    }
}
```

One example of SVG Bootstrap:

```
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
          class="bi bi-exclamation-octagon" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path
            d="M4.54.146A.5.5 0 0 1 4.893 0h6.214a.5.5 0 0 1 .353.146l4.394 4.394a.5.5 0 0 1 .146.353v6.214a.5.5 0 0 1-.146.353l-4.394 4.394a.5.5 0 0 1-.353.146H4.893a.5.5 0 0 1-.353-.146L.146 11.46A.5.5 0 0 1 0 11.107V4.893a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.353L4.54.146zM5.1 1 1 5.1v5.8L5.1 15h5.8l4.1-4.1V5.1L10.9 1H5.1z" />
          <path
            d="M7.002 11a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zM7.1 4.995a.905.905 0 1 1 1.8 0l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 4.995z" />
        </svg>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use CSS to change the colour, you could also use an online tool like this one: *[Change SVG Color Using CSS Filter](https://change-svg-color.vercel.app/)*

Comment: That answer is uninformative, it doesn't explain how to do it, nor that it's an svg filter. It would be better to comment on the top-voted answer and provide a link to that tool, which is an alternative to the codepen.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest trick is to change the color using jQuery on page load.

```
      $(document).ready(function () { 
              $('svg').find('path').attr('fill', '#FFF');
      });
```

`#FFF` is the color code that you want to set.

Comment: This is a rather convoluted approach. But it can be used if you don't have access to actually change the SVG directly in the code.

Comment: & This code also useful if element loads after ajax request completion or in ajax response

Answer (score -3):

You can change the svg color using **fill** attribute

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" fill="#colorcode">
    Your svg path here
</svg>
```

[Check demo here](https://www.codesprogram.com/snippet/j8tvcY)

Comment: Obviously, but please **read the original question** as well as the **previous (39) answers** before adding a new answer.  You can't apply `fill` to `<image>` or `<img>` elements.

Comment: You know its the wrong way to add svg. Who asked this question already know this question is just waste of time but he asked this question. He can ask that type of question and i can't add answer in the right way.

Comment: There are many ways to attach and handle svgs – sometimes you might be restricted by a certain environment (CMS, framework, library etc.). I don't blame you, since there are a lot of answers in this thread **completely ignoring** the OP's questions.
However, you should always refer to the initial problem and if not exactly solving the issue explain, why the OP should concider to choose an alternative approach (like inlined svg, use native web-components, external `<use>` references or even icon fonts etc.).

Comment: Please make sure, your answer adds a **new and unique approach/insight** to the thread. 
Assuming that the OP should know that his approach is not working - that is not very helpful. BTW. I haven't downvoted, since I'm more interested in encouraging new contributors to improve their answers. Please prefer code examples via SO's snippets - hosted snippets might expire.

Answer (score -4):

The shortest [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29)-compatible way, no JavaScript:

```
.cameraicon {
    height: 1.6em; /* Set your own icon size */
    mask: url(/camera.svg); /* Path to your image */
   -webkit-mask: url(/camera.svg) no-repeat center;
}
```

And use it like:

```
<td class="text-center">
    <div class="bg-secondary cameraicon"/><!-- "bg-secondary" sets actual color of your icon -->
</td>
```