# Use PostCSS: Inline-SVG with editable linear gradients

Tags: css, svg, linear-gradients, postcss

There is this super awesome plugin for postcss called postcss-inline-svg.
I use it all the time to load svg icons in different styles from only one source.

If you haven't heard of it, make sure to check it out on Github:
https://github.com/TrySound/postcss-inline-svg

If you are already familiar with the plug in, you probably know that you are able to change fills of svg image when loading via svg-load().

I would like to know, if its possible to define linear gradients to load them into the fill of a svg image.

Something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="greenish">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A4C660"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#45995B"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="test" viewBox="0 0 102.0469 102.0479" width="102" height="102" fill="url(#greenish)">
        <path d="M98.4473,0H0V102.0479H102.0469V0Zm-2.835,95.6123H6.4346V6.4346H95.6123Z"/>
        <circle cx="33.4389" cy="38.1854" r="6.8354"/>
        <path d="M17.3242,76.1865H64.6587A13.4873,13.4873,0,1,0,84.7568,61.3074V24.0762A2.5505,2.5505,0,0,0,82.1855,21.5H17.3242a2.5421,2.5421,0,0,0-2.5713,2.5757v49.539A2.5459,2.5459,0,0,0,17.3242,76.1865ZM85.96,63.8018a1.6524,1.6524,0,0,1,.6816,2.2382L78.1689,81.9551a1.647,1.647,0,0,1-1.2646.8633,1.4522,1.4522,0,0,1-.1943.0117,1.6552,1.6552,0,0,1-1.2373-.5537l-8.0616-9.0977a1.6533,1.6533,0,0,1,2.4746-2.1933L76.3682,78.3l7.3564-13.8144A1.6537,1.6537,0,0,1,85.96,63.8018Zm-66.6368-37.73H80.1875V59.5352c.0257.0048.056.0142.0823.02a13.3865,13.3865,0,0,0-7.662.7542L65.9131,49.64,56.2324,34.2148,46.5586,49.64l-2.64,4.2056-4.0724-6.3544-5.6382,8.7969-5.64,8.7969H51.1221l-.0131-.02h15.55a13.4211,13.4211,0,0,0-2.4459,7.7343c0,.1351.0162.266.02.4-.0123-.1452-.02-.2815-.02-.4,0-.3984.0205-.792.0547-1.1816H19.3232Z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

This is how I load it in my HTML File:

```
<svg role="img" class="test-svg">
            <use xlink:href="assets/images/svg/test.svg#test"/>
        </svg>
```

Download the test file here:
[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B89oIuOBdiu0MGxELVdkekRRZU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you tried `svg-load(demo.svg, fill="url(#myGradient)");` (not sure if you need the quotes)

Comment: @simonHänisch nice hint, this works, but only in firefox, in chrome somehow my svg stays blank

Comment: ok maybe you need to wrap your gradient definition in a `<defs>` block?

Comment: @SimonHänisch yh, I already did that, I update my SVG code, take a look above

Comment: does this work in chrome: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp ?

Comment: I actually dont' use the postcss plug in right now

Comment: @SimonHänisch yes that works

Comment: if you specify a symbol, you need to use it with `<use/>` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol)

Comment: @SimonHänisch look above, that's actually how I do

Comment: Can you post or link the generated SVG that appears blank in Chrome?  Also make sure that you don't have more than one gradient with the same `id`.

Comment: sure, you can download the file here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B89oIuOBdiu0MGxELVdkekRRZU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MartenZander if you do this: `<use xlink:href="#test"/>`, then it works for me... (https://jsfiddle.net/bpnubt39/1/) can you explain, what you want to achieve with your `xlink:href`?

Comment: @SimonHänisch what browser are you using? And where di you put your use-tag ? In my Project-Environment I have to set the target like so: <use xlink:href="assets/images/svg/test.svg#test" />

Comment: ahh I see, you actually put the whole svg inline... What I want to do is load the svg with a use tag and not have to put it inline

Comment: then you can't change the fill color (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22253046/2897426) ... if I get it right that is exactly what the postcss-inline-svg plugin is for (loading the image and then inlining it so it can be manipulated). don't know why it doesn't work with the gradient in chrome. you can open an issue on github, actually there is one about single/double quotes in chrome dev tools (https://github.com/TrySound/postcss-inline-svg/issues/20). there is also a solution using jquery to inline the svg: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933495/2897426 ...