# How to change color of an SVG in Angular JS

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I used src in my code and when i want to be active , i want to change the color of the svg that i used . 
HTML:

```
<img src="../icons/Burgers.svg" class="icon" />
```

so i used in icon-menu-bar css :

```
.icon{
fill:red;
}
```

but the SVG doesn't changed .
SO the main problem is change svg color in my html , and the SVG is on different file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change svg color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/change-svg-color)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the icon SVG, you should convert SVG images to a font (https://icomoon.io/app/#/select), and after that include it to own project and change color.

P.S: A lot off UI libraries have own set of icons, for example:

- (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/)
- (https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)

Comment: i have a graphic designer that make my SVG

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-include to import svg elements to code, then select your specific element from imported svg and change css . 
for example :

```
<div class="icon svg" ng-include=" '/assets/img/icon.svg' " > </div>

.icon.svg svg {
  fill:red;
}
```

hope this help your time.