# How do I add color to my svg image in react

Tags: html, reactjs, css

I have a list of icons. I want to change the icons colors to white. By default my icons are black. 
Any suggestions guys?

I normally use `'fill: white'` in my css but now that I am doing this in React... it's not working!

```
import React from 'react'
import menuIcon from '../img/menu.svg';
import homeIcon from '../img/home.svg';


<ul>
   <li>
    <a href="/" className="sidebar__link">
     <img src={menuIcon} alt="sidebar icon" className="sidebar__icon" />
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="/" className="sidebar__link">
     <img src={homeIcon} alt="sidebar icon" className="sidebar__icon" />
    </a>
   </li>
</ul>



.sidebar__icon {
 fill: #FFFFF;
 width: 3.2rem;
 height: 3.2rem;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the style attribute ? `<img src={homeIcon} style={{fill:"#FFFFFF"}} alt="sidebar icon" className="sidebar__icon" />`

Comment: No i did not use...I am using sass inn an external file

Comment: Anyway you can use online style attribute

Answer (score 59, accepted):

use your SVG as a component, then all the SVG goodness is accessible:

```
const MenuIcon = (props) =>(
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill={props.fill} className={props.class}></svg>
)
```

And in your render

```
<li>
   <a href="/" className="sidebar__link">
      <MenuIcon fill="white"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but do i have to create component for all the my icons? I have about 5 icons to include.

Comment: That's the way to manipulate the SVG DOM, yes. The only other option is to use css filters on the <img>

Comment: Anyway, it would be kind of you and maybe helpful for others with the same question in mind if you marked this question as answered.

Comment: Hey Bibi... I worked, I am new to react so it took a while to get it...thanks again!

Comment: did you forget the src attribute?

Comment: No, this example does not use an external file as a source but rather contains the code of the svg itself.

Comment: You can use tools like https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/ to automatically create react components from SVG files.

Answer (score 118):

I use this approach to avoid the need of creating a React component for each icon. As the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs) say you can import the SVG file as a react component.

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo />
  </div>
);
```

If you want to change the fill property you have to set your SVG `fill`'s value to `current` then you can use it like this:

```
<svg fill="current" stroke="current" ....> ... </svg>
```

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo fill='red' stroke='green'/>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2020. If you use `fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor"` in the svg, then you can do things like `style={{ textColor: 'blue' }}` on the component.

Comment: also works if the inline color should apply on the `<path>`, inside the `<svg>`. instead of putting the `fill='current'` on the `<svg>` tag, put it on the `<path>` tag inside it.

`<svg> <path fill='current'></path></ svg>`

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but when I did this using svgs I made in inkscape, there was also a style tag at the bottom of the svg with fill=#000000 that was overriding my color preferences. I deleted that line and it worked. If you're doing this method and it still isn't updating or only the stroke is updating, then that might be worth considering.

Comment: Earlier created wrapper component around each svg, then gave props for stroke, etc. This solution is simple & excellent, tx

Answer (score 39):

You can change css of svg by accessing **g** or **path**.
Starting from create-react-app version 2.0

```
import React from 'react'
import {ReactComponent as Icon} from './home.svg';

export const Home = () => {

    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <Icon className='home__icon'/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

```
.home__icon g {
 fill: #FFFFF;
}
.home__icon path {
 stroke: #e5e5e5;
 stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I found an interesting solution to this problem. Don't know if it works in all cases though...
Okay so I have an svg that import like:

```
import LockIcon from "../assets/lock.svg"
```

and then render it as:

```
<LockIcon color={theme.colors.text.primary} />
```

and then in lock.svg I just add `fill="currentColor"` in the svg tag.

Hopefully this can useful for some of you.

Comment: Wow, Idk why but it's working!! Underrated solution, thanks!

Comment: I assume that both of you are using Create React App, which uses [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) under the hood to automatically turn SVG icons into React components.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change the color of svg without changing the style of svg or without doing any change in the code of svg itself.

You can change the color of svg as an image also.

This can be done with applying filter property of css.
[Change your color to css filter](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp).

For the blue

- Hex code = #0000ff
- blue to filter: `invert(9%) sepia(99%) saturate(5630%) hue-rotate(246deg) brightness(111%) contrast(148%);`

code

```
<img src="path/to/svg" 
  style={{filter: "invert(9%) sepia(99%) saturate(5630%) hue-rotate(246deg) brightness(111%) contrast(148%)"}} 
/>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/11966205)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I needed to delete this part of my svg file to make it work:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#8AC6F4;}
</style>
```

an then this works

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can finally do `<Logo fill={"#ff00ff"} />` to change the color

Answer (score 4):

I use this approach:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo fill='red' stroke='green'/>
  </div>
);
```

Although you don't have to set colors to current in SVG to make it work.

```
<svg fill="current" stroke="current" ....> ... </svg>
```

You can keep some default colors so that you don't have to set them in React component each time you are using the SVG, but only when it's necessary.

```
<svg fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" ....> ... </svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of React `16.13.1`, you can use the SVG directly as a component and pass `fill` prop to change the colour. Please have a look at the following example:

`home.svg`

```
<svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px"><path d="M 12 2.0996094 L 1 12 L 4 12 L 4 21 L 11 21 L 11 15 L 13 15 L 13 21 L 20 21 L 20 12 L 23 12 L 12 2.0996094 z M 12 4.7910156 L 18 10.191406 L 18 11 L 18 19 L 15 19 L 15 13 L 9 13 L 9 19 L 6 19 L 6 10.191406 L 12 4.7910156 z"/></svg>
```

`ShowIcon/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';

import HomeIcon from './home.svg';

const ShowIcon = props => {
    return (
        <HomeIcon fill='#ccc' />
    )
}

export default ShowIcon;
```

However, I noticed after testing with several icons that it doesn't work with all the icons. So, please test it before using.

Comment: Just a note: if this isn't working with your icon, it's very likely because the icon has a hard-coded fill color rather than using `fill="currentColor"` in the appropriate places. Replacing the hard-coded value with `fill="currentColor"` will probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ****fill**** attribute of the path tag  inside your .svg file is set to "none" otherwise this won't work

```
<Icon fill="white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove all of the `fill` tag under the SVG tag and then add the `fill` tag to SVG only then it works.

This is Before:

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="29"
      height="29"
      viewBox="0 0 29 29"
      fill="white"
    >
      <g clip-path="url(#clip0_748_6465)">
        <path
          d="M1.40032 26.3262H3.04082C3.49381 26.3262 3.86107 25.959 3.86107 25.506V16.4832H1.40032C0.94733 16.4832 0.580078 16.8505 0.580078 17.3035V25.506C0.580078 25.9589 0.94733 26.3262 1.40032 26.3262ZM22.0159 1.71875C18.3917 1.71875 15.4539 4.6566 15.4539 8.28072C15.4539 11.9047 18.3917 14.8427 22.0159 14.8427C25.64 14.8427 28.5778 11.9047 28.5778 8.28072C28.5778 4.6566 25.64 1.71875 22.0159 1.71875ZM23.3905 11.2328C23.2128 11.3217 23.0266 11.3916 22.836 11.4445V11.6712C22.836 12.1242 22.4687 12.4914 22.0158 12.4914C21.5628 12.4914 21.1955 12.1242 21.1955 11.6712V11.4702C20.8541 11.3842 20.5356 11.2397 20.2659 11.0374C19.9035 10.7656 19.83 10.2515 20.1018 9.88906C20.3737 9.52673 20.8878 9.45319 21.2502 9.72502C21.5783 9.97109 22.2093 9.98935 22.6568 9.76559C22.8367 9.67564 22.9337 9.56736 22.9337 9.5112C22.9337 9.41305 22.9337 9.3979 22.8246 9.33966C22.6105 9.22543 22.2321 9.15522 21.8661 9.08736C21.3775 8.99669 20.8723 8.90296 20.4345 8.6693C19.7952 8.32808 19.4573 7.76829 19.4573 7.05046C19.4573 6.33182 19.8883 5.70416 20.6397 5.32849C20.8177 5.2399 21.0038 5.16872 21.1955 5.11594V4.89048C21.1955 4.43749 21.5628 4.07023 22.0158 4.07023C22.4687 4.07023 22.836 4.43749 22.836 4.89048V5.09133C23.1775 5.17735 23.4959 5.32198 23.7656 5.52426C24.128 5.79609 24.2015 6.31022 23.9297 6.6726C23.6578 7.03499 23.1438 7.10848 22.7813 6.83665C22.4527 6.5902 21.8211 6.57193 21.3733 6.79575C21.1924 6.8862 21.0978 6.99234 21.0978 7.05041C21.0978 7.14862 21.0978 7.16371 21.2069 7.222C21.421 7.33624 21.7994 7.40645 22.1654 7.47431C22.654 7.56498 23.1592 7.6587 23.597 7.89236C24.2363 8.23359 24.5742 8.79338 24.5742 9.5112C24.5743 10.2291 24.1428 10.8567 23.3905 11.2328ZM15.3883 26.7637H15.5688C18.3248 26.7308 20.9659 25.949 23.2956 24.538L27.8725 21.3391C28.6435 20.7977 28.7912 19.7806 28.2826 19.0588C27.7576 18.3041 26.7405 18.1237 26.0023 18.6487L21.6058 21.7328C20.195 22.5531 18.4725 22.7335 16.914 22.2085L11.8558 20.5352C11.4293 20.404 11.1995 19.9282 11.3472 19.5018C11.4784 19.0916 11.905 18.862 12.3315 18.9768C12.3479 18.9768 18.0131 20.8142 18.0131 20.8142C18.9671 21.1001 19.8146 20.5603 20.0801 19.7642C20.3589 18.8947 19.8832 17.976 19.0302 17.6972L11.3144 15.1709C9.62674 14.5565 7.35253 14.6834 5.50156 15.7185V24.9009L11.9378 26.359C13.1168 26.6184 14.2737 26.7637 15.3883 26.7637Z"
           fill="#28A745"
        />
      </g>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0_748_6465">
          <rect
            width="28"
            height="28"
            fill="white"
            transform="translate(0.580078 0.242188)"
          />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

And this is after:

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="29"
      height="29"
      viewBox="0 0 29 29"
      fill="white"
    >
      <g clip-path="url(#clip0_748_6465)">
        <path
          d="M1.40032 26.3262H3.04082C3.49381 26.3262 3.86107 25.959 3.86107 25.506V16.4832H1.40032C0.94733 16.4832 0.580078 16.8505 0.580078 17.3035V25.506C0.580078 25.9589 0.94733 26.3262 1.40032 26.3262ZM22.0159 1.71875C18.3917 1.71875 15.4539 4.6566 15.4539 8.28072C15.4539 11.9047 18.3917 14.8427 22.0159 14.8427C25.64 14.8427 28.5778 11.9047 28.5778 8.28072C28.5778 4.6566 25.64 1.71875 22.0159 1.71875ZM23.3905 11.2328C23.2128 11.3217 23.0266 11.3916 22.836 11.4445V11.6712C22.836 12.1242 22.4687 12.4914 22.0158 12.4914C21.5628 12.4914 21.1955 12.1242 21.1955 11.6712V11.4702C20.8541 11.3842 20.5356 11.2397 20.2659 11.0374C19.9035 10.7656 19.83 10.2515 20.1018 9.88906C20.3737 9.52673 20.8878 9.45319 21.2502 9.72502C21.5783 9.97109 22.2093 9.98935 22.6568 9.76559C22.8367 9.67564 22.9337 9.56736 22.9337 9.5112C22.9337 9.41305 22.9337 9.3979 22.8246 9.33966C22.6105 9.22543 22.2321 9.15522 21.8661 9.08736C21.3775 8.99669 20.8723 8.90296 20.4345 8.6693C19.7952 8.32808 19.4573 7.76829 19.4573 7.05046C19.4573 6.33182 19.8883 5.70416 20.6397 5.32849C20.8177 5.2399 21.0038 5.16872 21.1955 5.11594V4.89048C21.1955 4.43749 21.5628 4.07023 22.0158 4.07023C22.4687 4.07023 22.836 4.43749 22.836 4.89048V5.09133C23.1775 5.17735 23.4959 5.32198 23.7656 5.52426C24.128 5.79609 24.2015 6.31022 23.9297 6.6726C23.6578 7.03499 23.1438 7.10848 22.7813 6.83665C22.4527 6.5902 21.8211 6.57193 21.3733 6.79575C21.1924 6.8862 21.0978 6.99234 21.0978 7.05041C21.0978 7.14862 21.0978 7.16371 21.2069 7.222C21.421 7.33624 21.7994 7.40645 22.1654 7.47431C22.654 7.56498 23.1592 7.6587 23.597 7.89236C24.2363 8.23359 24.5742 8.79338 24.5742 9.5112C24.5743 10.2291 24.1428 10.8567 23.3905 11.2328ZM15.3883 26.7637H15.5688C18.3248 26.7308 20.9659 25.949 23.2956 24.538L27.8725 21.3391C28.6435 20.7977 28.7912 19.7806 28.2826 19.0588C27.7576 18.3041 26.7405 18.1237 26.0023 18.6487L21.6058 21.7328C20.195 22.5531 18.4725 22.7335 16.914 22.2085L11.8558 20.5352C11.4293 20.404 11.1995 19.9282 11.3472 19.5018C11.4784 19.0916 11.905 18.862 12.3315 18.9768C12.3479 18.9768 18.0131 20.8142 18.0131 20.8142C18.9671 21.1001 19.8146 20.5603 20.0801 19.7642C20.3589 18.8947 19.8832 17.976 19.0302 17.6972L11.3144 15.1709C9.62674 14.5565 7.35253 14.6834 5.50156 15.7185V24.9009L11.9378 26.359C13.1168 26.6184 14.2737 26.7637 15.3883 26.7637Z"
        />
      </g>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0_748_6465">
          <rect
            width="28"
            height="28"
            transform="translate(0.580078 0.242188)"
          />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

The **fill** in **rect** and **path** was removed

Answer (score 0):

Just add class to your path or polygon and then you can style it like other dom elements from css.

svg

```html
<svg
   viewBox="0 0 194.33945 148.38944"
   version="1.1"
   id="info"
   width="194.33945"
   height="148.38943"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon
     class="info-cls"
     points="45.69,29.72 6.73,68.67 45.69,68.67 "
   />
</svg>
```

css

```css
svg .info-cls  {
  fill: #ffdabe;
  stroke: #97380f;
}
```

Comment: That css wont work in case the svg is used as a src of an image `<img src="example.svg"/>`

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to use a tool like SVG to font convertor, [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) is my favorite, create your own custom font library for importing your SVG icons

Props

- Change color, font size, etc with CSS for icons
- Use in the entire project with a single import
- They are providing some free icons/ icons bundle

Cons

- Initial learning curve
- Properly follow the dimensions, outline etc while creating an SVG icons
- Difficult for multicolor icons

Comment: A final, but big con is accessibility - this approach removes all text in an svg that is readable (tooltip, description, and title), thereby making it useless in readers for users with accessibility challenges.

Comment: Thanks for the point, I am always trying to keep a custom title whenever it's required.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, tried most of the suggestions with no luck.

I solved it in a very simple way... no need to create a component for the SVG image

**>>> Only add the wanted color as fill in `<path fill='#9d8189' ...></path>` in .svg file**