# Can i import the SVG file as a react component with dynamic import() Expressions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62532186/15704277) from stackoverflow, I got a solution on how to import svg as *ReactComponent* and change their color/width, etc.

But is it possible to do the same for dynamic import?
My functional component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import SvgIconComponent from './SvgIcon.Interface';

import {ReactComponent} from '*.svg';

const SvgIcon: React.FC<SvgIconComponent> =({width, color, name}) =>
{
    import(`../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`).then((Icon) => {
        return <Icon fill={color} width={width}/>
    });
};

export default SvgIcon;
```

In the current implementation I get errors:

```
TS2749: 'ReactComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. // .then((Icon as ReactComponent)

TS2604: JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures. // .then(Icon)
```

Comment: The Error represents that there is no html attribute called Icon. you can try using <i> or <span>

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your issue is that you are importing the whole file and trying to render that as a component, you need to append the key / component identifier/const name to the require. For example if you use export defualt YourSVGComponent you can access that dynamically by doing the following;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import SvgIconComponent from './SvgIcon.Interface';

const SvgIcon: React.FC<SvgIconComponent> =({width, color, name}) =>
{
    const Icon = require(`../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`).default
    return <Icon fill={color} width={width}/>
};

export default SvgIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of mistakes here.

#### `'ReactComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

The `ReactComponent` that you are seeing in the linked answer is actually a property of the `.svg` file when it is loaded by Create React App.  It is a super neat feature which I am just learning about for the first time today!

In that [example code](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs)

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
```

What they are doing is taking the `ReactComponent` property from the `'./logo.svg'` import and renaming it to `Logo`.

Your `import {ReactComponent} from '*.svg';` doesn't make much sense.

You get the "type as value" error when using `ReactComponent` as a type because it is not a type.  The type assertion that you were attempting to do with `.then((Icon as ReactComponent)` should have been `.then((Icon as React.ComponentType<SomePropsType>)`.

#### `JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Let's take a moment to see what we actually get from the `import` statement.

```
import(`../../assets/icons/${name}.svg`).then(console.log);
```

You should see an object with three properties: `ReactComponent`, `default`, and `Url`.

```
{
  ReactComponent: ƒ SvgLogo(),
  default: "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i...",
  Url: "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i..."
}
```

The `default` import from the svg file (which is also the `Url` property) is the data-url for the image.  You can use that in an `img` `src` property.

The `ReactComponent` is the property that we are after!  That's where Create React App converts the svg into a React component.  (Note: the name "SvgLogo" depends on the name of the file).

#### `Nothing was returned from render.`

Nothing is returned from your `SvgIcon` function.  The `return` statement that you have is the return for the `then` callback.

Dealing with an asynchronous `import` is a bit tricky, as you won't have a value on the first render.  In that case we can return `null` (or you might want to return a sized placeholder).

Here I am using the `element` state to store the returned element.  It starts as `null` and gets replaced with the `<Icon/>` after it has been loaded.

I am calling the `import` inside of a `useEffect` with dependencies on your props.  Once the import resolves, we get the `Icon` from `res.ReactComponent`.

The inferred type for `Icon` is `any`, which might be fine for you.  If you want an accurate type, you can use the messy `as React.ComponentType<JSX.IntrinsicElements['svg']>;` which says "this is a React component which takes all of the props of an `<svg>` element".

```
import * as React from "react";

interface SVGIconProps {
  width: string | number;
  color: string;
  name: string;
}

const SvgIcon: React.FC<SVGIconProps> = ({ width, color, name }) => {
  const [element, setElement] = React.useState<JSX.Element | null>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    import(`./icons/${name}.svg`).then((res) => {
      const Icon = res.ReactComponent as React.ComponentType<JSX.IntrinsicElements['svg']>;
      setElement(<Icon fill={color} width={width} />);
    });
  }, [name, color, width]);

  return element;
};

export default SvgIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to render your svg. Have all your svg files inside `public` folder, let's say inside `public/svgFiles`.

you can then use it as
`<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/svgFiles/" + file_name} alt="project" />`

Since everything from the public folder is included in the final `build`, all your svg files will be taken care of, along with the path you use, since everything will be referred from public folder, path will not be changed after build.

---

Approach 2

Import SVG as a react component in this way:

```js
import { ReactComponent as MY_SVG_COMPONENT } from '/path/to/svg'
```

Now you can pass all the props that are available in a SVGComponent, like

```js
<MY_SVG_COMPONENT className="my-svg-class" />
```

Comment: I went with this solution after tiring of fighting Typescript errors. Bypass the byzantine. Create-react-app documentation on the public folder is [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

Comment: You can try the updated answer, with importing svg as React component -- 
import { ReactComponent as MY_SVG_COMPONENT } from '/path/to/svg'

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a better way to use the React component to make the dynamic icons for the color and width.

I add my example code:

```
export const TwitterIcon = ({color, width}: Props) => (
    <svg
        width={width ? width : 24}
        height={width ? width : 24}
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
        <path
            fill={color ? color : "#1f1f1f"}
            d="M8.0798 19.9998C9.55849 20.0493 11.0321 19.8018 12.4135 19.2721C13.795 18.7424 15.0562 17.9411 16.1227 16.9156C17.1892 15.8901 18.0393 14.6613 18.6228 13.3017C19.2063 11.9421 19.5113 10.4793 19.5198 8.9998C20.1974 8.16121 20.7006 7.19563 20.9998 6.1598C21.0221 6.07796 21.0203 5.99141 20.9946 5.91057C20.9689 5.82974 20.9203 5.75806 20.8548 5.70417C20.7893 5.65027 20.7096 5.61647 20.6253 5.60683C20.5411 5.59718 20.4558 5.6121 20.3798 5.6498C20.0253 5.82045 19.6262 5.87558 19.2386 5.80741C18.8511 5.73923 18.4948 5.5512 18.2198 5.2698C17.8687 4.88538 17.4441 4.57533 16.971 4.35803C16.498 4.14072 15.9861 4.02059 15.4657 4.00473C14.9454 3.98888 14.4272 4.07763 13.9417 4.26574C13.4563 4.45384 13.0136 4.73746 12.6398 5.0998C12.128 5.59546 11.7531 6.21509 11.5516 6.89847C11.3501 7.58186 11.3288 8.30575 11.4898 8.9998C8.1398 9.1998 5.8398 7.6098 3.9998 5.4298C3.94452 5.3672 3.87221 5.32205 3.7917 5.29987C3.71119 5.27769 3.62596 5.27943 3.54642 5.30488C3.46688 5.33033 3.39648 5.37839 3.3438 5.4432C3.29113 5.508 3.25846 5.58674 3.2498 5.6698C2.89927 7.61422 3.15213 9.61935 3.97442 11.4159C4.7967 13.2124 6.14904 14.7143 7.8498 15.7198C6.70943 17.0276 5.10801 17.8445 3.3798 17.9998C3.28721 18.0152 3.20174 18.0591 3.13535 18.1254C3.06896 18.1917 3.02497 18.2772 3.00954 18.3698C2.99411 18.4623 3.00801 18.5574 3.0493 18.6417C3.09059 18.726 3.15719 18.7952 3.2398 18.8398C4.74332 19.5912 6.39903 19.988 8.0798 19.9998Z"
        />
    </svg>
);
```

And if you want to make the icons library

```
interface IconProps {
   keyword: string; //make the clear type to make switch
   color: string;
   width: number;
}

const SvgIcon = ({keyword, color, width}: IconProps) => {
   // In this case you have to think about the switch and types in typescript.
    return (
       {
           'twitter': <TwitterIcon color={color} width={width}/>,
           'facebook': <FacebookIcon color={color} width={width}/>,
       }[keyword]
   )
}

//in component
<SvgIcon keyword='twitter' width={24} color='red'/>
```

If you have too many SVG icons, I don't have any solution for it on my hands right now. If I have any good idea with it. I will post here again.

Comment: This does not answer how to import the SVG dynamically, which I presume is precisely i order to avoid doing what you've done.

Answer (score -3):

```
import MyIcon from '../../assets/icons/${name}.svg'

<MyIcon />
```