# How to change the color of an svg element in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I need to load, display and dynamically change the color of an SVG image in my Angular project by applying different CSS classes to it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element) didn't help, since it makes use of the Modernizr library and I would like to avoid it. I don't want also to copy the `d` field in the `path` tag of the image I have directly in the html file of the Angular project because it would be a wall of text that I'm not willing to accept. I can accept instead the usage of an external dedicated library to achieve the correct outcome, like the [ng-inline-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inline-svg), which I tried to use the following way:

```
<div class="svg1" aria-label="My icon"
   [inlineSVG]="'./assets/images/icons/ApplyIcon.svg'">
</div>
```

Defying the following CSS class:

```
.svg1 {
  color: green;
}
```

It loads the image perfectly as a regular `img` tag but if I try then to apply a custom class to it to change the image color, it doesn't work.

Furthermore, I tried to use the object tag the following way:

```
<div class="col-2">
    <object
       id="svg1"
       data="./assets/images/icons/ApplyIcon.svg"
       type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
</div>
```

But, again, if I apply a class to the object tag with the CSS directives `color: green;` or `fill: green;` nothing would change. Any idea to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the svg element in component.html file and use [ngClass] directive to dynamically change the inner svg class based on the conditions.

example:

component.ts

```
data.state = "New" || "In-Progress" || "Completed" // this changes dynamically based on the data
```

component.html:

```
<svg <circle class="cls-3" [ngClass] = "{'New': 'blue', 'In-Progress':'orange','Completed':'green'}[data.state]" cx="8.21" cy="8.01" r="2.44" transform="translate(-3.22 8.89) rotate(-48.73)"/></svg> // inner class of svg element
```

component.css:

```
.blue {
    fill:blue
}
.orange{
   fill: orange
}
.green {
   fill: green
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ways to change img src SVG colors finally achieved using SVG as a mask and  It's working as expected for me.

Angular HTML:

```
 <div class="icon" [ngStyle]="{'mask': 'url(' + icon + ') no-repeat center', '-webkit-mask': 'url(' + icon + ') no-repeat center'}"></div>
```

Angular  CSS

```
 .icon {
    background-color: #0000; // Here you can the svg color
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to dynamically change the color of specific paths and circles within an SVG element using Angular. Here's how I achieved it:

1. Declare a color variable in your Angular component:

   ```js
   export class YourComponent {
           color: string = 'yourDefaultColor';
       }
   ```
2. In your HTML template, use property binding to dynamically set the fill attribute of the SVG elements:

   ```html
   <svg>
         <path [attr.fill]="color" ... />
         <!-- Other SVG elements -->
   </svg>
   ```

Ensure to replace `'yourDefaultColor'` with your desired default color.

Comment: how you will pass the <color>? from component or from html? can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setAttribute()` property to change the color of the SVG,

```
document.getElementById("svg1").setAttribute("fill", "green");
```

Comment: Applying directly `style="fill: green;"` to the `object` tag doesn't work, as I explained in my question, so why should this work? Furthermore, in Angular projects we should avoid accessing the DOM directly like you're doing here because that's Angular’s sphere of control.

Answer (score 0):

```
fill: green;
```

works only for path element which is usually present in svg element.
color property is for font color and it won't work on svg element.
In your scenario you can below things 
1) in your folder /assets/images/icons/ApplyIcon.svg edit svg icon and for that path
   give attribute fill="green"
2) If you want to use that icon on multiple places with different color then above method 
   will not work because same color will get applied everywhere. In this case you can simply remove fill="color" from all path inside svg.
and after this you can apply css

```
fill:color;
```

In this case although fill:color is not applied on SVG it will traverse to child element path and hence it will work.

Comment: I noticed that the `fill: green` is correctly applied for the `path` element, but unfortunately your solution (1) doesn't work for me because I need to change that image color according to a status and I really would avoid solution (2) because I see it as an unnecessary overload. Isn't there really no other way to apply a `fill` property to a SVG image in Angular? Or rather, to load an SVG image as an icon maybe and change its color by applying a CSS class?

Comment: simply add inline svg icon instead of giving path of scg icon.
now in path of svg you can dynamically change fill attribute based on your status.

Comment: Could you elaborate it more and/or provide an example, please?

Comment: added that in answer

Comment: In question you have mentioned that you don't want to put lengthy svg element in template so I think I approach will not work. I think without that you will not able to access  path element as it create another embedded document element.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this same issue and resolved it by generating a new Angular component and using my .svg file in place the the component's .html file.

For instance, updating the template path to point to your .svg, like this: `templateUrl: './my-icon.component.svg'`. You can then add Angular directives inside the SVG file.

Check out this example: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-svg-files-as-component-templates-with-angular-cli-ea58fe79b6c1

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good but then what if you have a bloated SVG?

we first need to transform the SVG or all SVG in the project using [@ngneat/svg-icon](https://github.com/ngneat/svg-icon)

[if the fill or stroke properties of elements in the SVG are set to currentColor, they will have the color defined for the containing DOM element,. So the color can easily be changed by changing the color style on the svg-icon element.](https://netbasal.com/elegantly-manage-svg-icons-in-angular-applications-5adde68a5c46)

move your SVGs icons to src/assets/svg directory the run `ng add @ngneat/svg-icon`

this command installs the svg-icon to your project and automatically generates the svgs into ts files where the svgs are turned to objects containing

- the `name` key : this is the generated name for the svg and will be used to identify the svg
- the `data` key: this is essentially the svg code copied from the svg files

the generated svg can be found on the app/svg directory

looking at the `app.module.ts` file the `SvgIconsModule` is imported and it is declared in the @Ngmodule imports.

import all the svg you want to use in the project from the app/svg directory and put it in the array of icons exposed by the `SvgIconsModule`.

```
import { SvgIconsModule } from '@ngneat/svg-icon';
import { appMasterCardLogoIcon, appPaypalLogoIcon, appVisaLogoIcon } from './svg';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SvgIconsModule.forRoot({
      icons: [appApplePayLogoIcon,
        appMasterCardLogoIcon,
        appPaypalLogoIcon,
        appVisaLogoIcon],
    })
  ],
 ...
})
```

you can now use the `svg-icon` tag anywhere in your component, then the attribute `key` will be the generated `name` key (used in identifying the svg)

because the fill or stroke property is set to currentColor, we can then use the `color` attribute on the `svg-icon` to control the color

we can also add a class to the `svg-icon` tag and control the styling using `ng-class`

```
<svg-icon key={{payment.logoKey}} [ngClass]="{'selected-payment': payment.isSelected}"class="payment-logo"></svg-icon>
```