# converting svg tags to embedded svg in image

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I want to create a responsive navbar using Tailwind CSS and followed this guide

https://youtu.be/ZT5vwF6Ooig?list=PL7CcGwsqRpSM3w9BT_21tUU8JN2SnyckR&t=74

Unfortunately there is no link for the SVG path so all I have is

```
<button>
  <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-700 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="... the missing svg path ..." />
  </svg>
</button>
```

So I tried to do it on my own with an external svg. For testing purposes I'm using this svg

https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/3324998/menu_icon

Due to the fact the svg has no `src` tag I decided to embed it within an `img` tag. I currently have

```css
img {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgc3Ryb2tlPSJjdXJyZW50Q29sb3IiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJyb3VuZCIgc3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luPSJyb3VuZCIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjQgMjQiIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48bGluZSB4MT0iMyIgeDI9IjIxIiB5MT0iMTIiIHkyPSIxMiIvPjxsaW5lIHgxPSIzIiB4Mj0iMjEiIHkxPSI2IiB5Mj0iNiIvPjxsaW5lIHgxPSIzIiB4Mj0iMjEiIHkxPSIxOCIgeTI9IjE4Ii8+PC9zdmc+");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.1.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button>
  <img class="h-6 w-6 text-red-700" />
</button>
```

I would expect the image to be red but it remains black. How can I fix the color for it? Further I'm not sure if more attributes are required. Maybe I don't have to embed it within an image tag and other solutions fit better?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can't modify an image color from CSS.
Instead of using an `img` tag, try to do something like that, so that you easily can change the jmenu color:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red; /* Here you can change your background color */
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this code can solve your problem.

---

EDIT:
I also found a nice solution to your problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/12203318) post:
Here you can see a demo that just uses CSS filter.

```css
.filter-red{
        filter: invert(47%) sepia(98%) saturate(7304%) hue-rotate(352deg) brightness(108%) contrast(130%);
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/24/menu-512.png" class="filter-red">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't want to create the menu by myself, I would like to use a designed svg.

Comment: What do you think about the second solution?

Comment: hm yes, this seems to be a good workaround :) I'll accept your answer but I'm hoping there will be an easier solution, because I would always have to calculate the filter when changing a color :/

Comment: Thanks man :-). Howewer, you can easily calculate the filter [here](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp): it's very fast. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the fill of an SVG using tailwind, using the *fill-current* class and then color it like any regular text, like this:

```
<svg class="w-4 h-4 fill-current text-gray-100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v2A5 5 0 0 1 5 7V5zM0 16.68A19.9 19.9 0 0 1 10 14c3.64 0 7.06.97 10 2.68V20H0v-3.32z"/>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the height and width of the SVG can also be set.