# Use the svg file dynamically and change the color dynamically in angular 9

Tags: angular, svg

I am building an angular 9 application that gets while running, svg file path parameters and I need to dynamically display it on screen.

I need to update the color of the SVG, according to the user's choice dynamically as well.
I tried to use the object element:

```
<object data = "assets/svg/female.svg" type = "image / svg + xml"> </object>
```

It shows me the svg file, but the style I put doesn't affect at all
How can write style to the SVG that come from object element?
or Is there another good way to add svg file dynamically?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element)

Comment: no, It doesn't answer me.                          
My question is in Angular 9, how to update color when using svg dynamically from svg file.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference in it, you are still using same styles. It also doesn't matter if the file is loaded dynamically.