# Unable to change the color of svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have tried to change the color of SVG to green.

First, I tried to use `fill`, but it only changes the background.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="green"/><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/>
</svg>
```

Also I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element#answer-53336754)

```html
<style>
    img .check{
        filter: invert(24%) sepia(100%) saturate(1648%) hue-rotate(96deg) brightness(97%) contrast(105%);
    }
    
</style>
<img class="check" src="check.svg">
```

However, It doesn't work too.
Hope for your help :-)

Comment: Assign `check` class to SVG

Comment: @Muhaddis Confused. I have already assigned `check` in my second approach.

Comment: Is this what your expected output looks like? https://gyazo.com/354128bfc458b786cd2acb9ffe27d08e

Comment: No. I have solved it.

Comment: add class in svg tag, not img tag

Comment: I mentioned the same

Comment: Thx. I misunderstood your proposal.

Comment: Maybe you can answer this more detailed. I will take your answer, not mine.

Comment: Not a problem @Zheyuuu. I am glad you sorted it out. There are already good answers on this topic :)

Comment: `img .check`--> `img.check`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `filter-class` in `<svg>`, not in `<img>`

```css
    .check{
        filter: invert(24%) sepia(100%) saturate(1648%) hue-rotate(96deg) brightness(97%) contrast(105%);
    }
```

```html
<svg class='check' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/>
</svg>
```

Get this: 
[image]