# How to change svg fill color on image tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the color of an `svg` image whenever the user hover this element, but for some reason, it doesn't change. I don't know if this is something about the format of my `svg`, but I think that there is nothing wrong with this.

In my researches, I found posts talking about the `filter` property, but it has too many options to change instead of just passing a `hex` or `rgb` color.

Here is my code:

```css
/* Tags */

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Ids */

#left-panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);
  position: absolute;
}

#play-btn {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  height: 40px;
}


/* Actions */

.svg:hover path {
  fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);">
  <div id="left-panel">
  </div>

  <footer>
    <img src="./components/src/icons/play-button.svg" id="play-btn" class="svg"/>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**SVG File**

```
<svg width="104" height="104" viewBox="0 0 104 104" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M52 3.75C25.3523 3.75 3.75 25.3523 3.75 52C3.75 78.6477 25.3523 100.25 52 100.25C78.6477 100.25 100.25 78.6477 100.25 52C100.25 25.3523 78.6477 3.75 52 3.75ZM0.25 52C0.25 23.4193 23.4193 0.25 52 0.25C80.5807 0.25 103.75 23.4193 103.75 52C103.75 80.5807 80.5807 103.75 52 103.75C23.4193 103.75 0.25 80.5807 0.25 52Z" fill="#B3B3B3"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M70.2891 52L42 72V32L70.2891 52Z" fill="#B3B3B3"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M41.1955 30.4459C41.7763 30.1452 42.4762 30.1935 43.0102 30.5711L71.2993 50.5711C71.7632 50.899 72.0391 51.4318 72.0391 52C72.0391 52.5682 71.7632 53.101 71.2993 53.429L43.0102 73.429C42.4762 73.8065 41.7763 73.8548 41.1955 73.5541C40.6147 73.2534 40.25 72.654 40.25 72V32C40.25 31.346 40.6147 30.7466 41.1955 30.4459ZM43.75 35.3804V68.6196L67.2576 52L43.75 35.3804Z" fill="#B3B3B3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I copied your code pulled it up in Chrome. It seems to be working for me. Here's a code pen of the code you provided: https://codepen.io/supermormon/pen/xxZzXVK What browser are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i'm using firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't style an svg if it's being imported with an `<img>` tag. I would check out this post that discusses a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element/

Comment: It does, thank you for your help.