# (Next.js) How can I change the color of SVG in next/image?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components, nextjs-image

```
import Image from 'next/image'

...

<Image src="/emotion.svg" alt="emtion" width={50} height={50} />
```

I want to change the SVG color in `next/image`.

But in CSS,

```
img {
  fill="#ffffff"
}
```

is not working.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 26):

I recommend you to not to use svg files directly, but use Playground SVG (https://react-svgr.com/playground/), convert the file to JS and then you can change the color and other stuff by props.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I changed the method using svg

Comment: I would like to know the benefit of doing that

Comment: sure @labs, by doing it, you can use state inside the SVG, e.x if you want to trigger something with hovering the SVG

Comment: That's cool , what about performance wise

Comment: This was by far the best solution for me. No crazy configuration necessary, just make an optimized React component out of the SVG. It even does Typescript.

Answer (score 14):

I think the best solution here is not to use `Image`. by default the `nextjs` `Image` component is not doing any optimization on `svg's`. You will then have multiple options/solutions to your problem:

1. Extend webpack config on your `next.config.js` file using `@svgr/webpack`:

```js
// next.config.js

webpack(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
  });

  return config;
}
```

```js
// The file where u want to import the svg
import YourSvg from './public/yourSvg.svg'

// I recommend using the `currentColor` property on your svg, but you can also pass the color as prop
<YourSvg color="red" />
```

2. Using `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg`: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/20993#discussioncomment-760119
   [image]

Comment: I don't understand why Nextjs is so bad with this. But thanks for confirming!

Comment: @NickW, truly. The `Image` component is practically useless to me because of all its limitations, despite all the warnings in building for prod.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Next/Image and inserting the SVG url dynamically. For this case I needed to use `css filter` to somehow change the SVG color.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

For anyone looking into this, follow this SO thread for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754

Answer (score 7):

```
<Link href={"/setting"} className="h-fit w-fit">
    <Image className="dark:invert"
        src={"/setting.svg"} alt={"setting.svg"} width={80} height={80} />
</Link>
```

Just use `invert` in tailwind css.

Edit: This just invert the color, which is useful for dark mode in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SVG files directly, convert them into React components. This approach removes the need for complex configurations.

**How to Convert:**

1. Use [transform.tools](https://transform.tools/) to convert your SVG into a React component.
2. In the SVG's JSX code, set all fill attributes to "currentColor". This lets you change the color through React props.

**Advantages:**

- Control SVG attributes like color, height, and width directly via props.
- Streamlined setup with no additional Webpack or Babel configurations needed.

**Example with Tailwind:**

```
<SVGIcon className="w-4 h-4 text-white" />
```

By following these steps, you'll have a much easier and flexible way to manage SVGs in your Next.js project.

Credit: This information is based on insights from Andres Campuzano Garzon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the filter property to the style prop of the  component.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
...

<Image src="/emotion.svg" alt="emtion" style={{ filter: 'invert(100%)' }} width={50} height={50} />
```

If you want to add a blue color to the SVG icon using the invert filter, you can modify the filter property accordingly. In this case, you want to invert the colors, which means turning the black areas white and the white areas black. To achieve a blue color, you need to invert these colors once more.

```
<Image src="/emotion.svg" alt="emtion" style={{ filter: 'invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(180deg)' }} width={50} height={50} />
```

You can adjust the sepia, saturate, and hue-rotate values to fine-tune the blue color to your liking. For example, reducing the saturate value will make the color less intense, and changing the hue-rotate value will adjust the shade of blue.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't changing the color. It's applying a filter.

Comment: It changes the color by applying a filter. It looks ugly, but it works. This answer gives a bit more detail including a link to a generator that can convert a hex color into filters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/1806628

Answer (score -2):

Well, the solution that I have found is practical. I edit the svg and change the color. When I select the svg in vscode it shows me all its configuration.

This svg will change the color to pink:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="128.000000pt" height="128.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 128.000000 128.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,128.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#D2485A" stroke="none">
<path d="M647 1233 c-13 -15 -17 -38 -17 -102 l0 -83 -84 -97 c-47 -53 -109
-123 -140 -156 l-55 -60 -1 58 0 57 -175 0 -175 0 0 -400 0 -400 175 0 175 0
0 31 c0 23 4 30 14 26 8 -3 57 -20 108 -38 l93 -33 265 -3 c300 -5 316 -2 354
72 17 33 18 43 8 81 -10 39 -9 48 8 76 22 36 26 98 9 129 -8 16 -5 26 15 50
28 33 35 93 16 129 -8 15 -4 27 15 56 30 44 32 88 5 131 -34 56 -61 63 -235
63 -106 0 -155 3 -155 11 0 6 7 36 16 66 25 85 17 198 -18 251 -52 78 -182
128 -221 85z m113 -85 c42 -29 70 -82 70 -133 0 -22 -13 -87 -30 -145 -16 -58
-30 -108 -30 -112 0 -5 87 -8 193 -8 158 0 197 -3 215 -16 40 -28 26 -80 -24
-90 -30 -6 -34 -10 -34 -39 0 -24 6 -34 24 -43 50 -22 41 -85 -14 -97 -25 -6
-30 -11 -30 -37 0 -20 8 -37 25 -50 27 -21 33 -59 12 -76 -6 -6 -24 -13 -40
-17 -23 -6 -27 -13 -27 -40 0 -25 5 -35 20 -40 24 -7 37 -51 23 -74 -9 -14
-44 -16 -279 -16 l-269 0 -107 39 -108 38 0 215 0 216 88 95 c262 286 262 285
262 379 0 82 6 87 60 51z m-480 -698 l0 -320 -100 0 -100 0 0 320 0 320 100 0
100 0 0 -320z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

here where it says fill I change the color:

```
<g transform="translate(0.000000,128.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#D2485A" stroke="none">
```

Comment: This is a very smooth path. Not suitable for 90% of tasks. Too often we need to access svg properties from code.

Comment: yes it works great if you only need to change it one time; but most of the time, you want to be able to customize the svg's color right on the jsx