# How to change the svg color using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

I tried to follow these steps:

[(Next.js) How can I change the color of SVG in next/image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676689/next-js-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-svg-in-next-image)

I'm using next.js too, but I'm unable to change the svg color

My next.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['raw.githubusercontent.com'],
  },
  entry: './components/Modal.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

but the svg doesn't show up and I get these errors in the console:

> next-dev.js?3515:32 Warning:  is using incorrect
> casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML
> elements.
> at watchProject

> next-dev.js?3515:32 Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in
> this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name
> with an uppercase letter.

My code:

```
import watchProject from "../public/icons/watch_project.svg";
[...]
<watchProject fill="blue"></watchProject>
```

If I use Image component the svg appear, but I can't change the properties

```
import watchProject from "../public/icons/watch_project.svg";
[...]
<Image src={watchProject} stroke="green" alt="star" width={18} height={18} />
```

Comment: Have you tried using `WatchProject` instead of `watchProject`?

Comment: That's not how webpack is configured in `next.config.js`. You need to pass the webpack config under the `webpack` property. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config.