# how to use an svg image in next app and change it's color dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, next-images

I have next 13 app with the app directory and I am trying to show an icon in a component, I was able to achieve this but not able to change the color of the svg image. Is there a way to achieve coloring for the svg image with next/Image or is there any other approach to achieve this?

```
import MenuIcon from "../../public/icons/menu.svg";
import Image from "next/image";
      
      {/* jsx */}
      {/* this works and the icon appears red */}
      <svg fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" viewBox="0 96 960 960" 
         width="48">
        <path d="M120 816v-60h720v60H120Zm0-210v-60h720v60H120Zm0-210v-60h720v60H120Z" />
      </svg>
      {/* this does not work */}
      <Image style={{ fill: "red" }} src={MenuIcon} alt="icon"></Image>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Next.js) How can I change the color of SVG in next/image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676689/next-js-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-svg-in-next-image)

Comment: This is not a Next.js problem. You cannot change the fill of an SVG if you render it as an image with `src`. It should be used as an HTML element if you want to manipulate ti.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://www.svgviewer.dev/) tool, paste you SVG. You will find react component for this SVG. Then check for prop to change the color of SVG in that component.