# How do I download colored font-awesome icons?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, font-awesome

Basically I want to download a font-awesome icon like this one

https://fontawesome.com/icons/window-minimize?style=solid

I need to download the image so that I can upload it to AWS. I want the version of this icon that is colored red, when I try to download the icon, it only gives me the black colored version. Is there a way to download the colored version of this icon? Or find a link that has the colored version of this icon?

If you can't help me to download the colored version of this icon, do you know of a way to change the color of the font awesome icon using a image tag?

I am currently trying (the src attribute is equal to an acutal link, I just dont want to put it on stack overflow)

```html
<img
  :src="https://..."
  :alt=""
  style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 20px; margin-right: 5px; color: red;"
/>
```

But this doesn't make the icon red

Comment: Note that you are downloading an `.svg` file. To color an svg file, you must use the `fill` css property, for example, `fill: red;`.

Comment: Exactly, more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web#adding_svg_to_your_pages

Comment: Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/4468084) for specifics on how exactly to color an SVG loaded from a file.