# How make svg color different

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an icon svg like:

```
<svg width="90" height="90">       
     <image xlink:href="{{asset('images/menu-icons/some-icon.svg')}}"/>    
</svg>
```

It is showing nice but i want to change the the color in some instances(like hover or selected)

I used:

```
.menu-item svg{
    fill: red!IMPORTANT;
}
```

It doesn't change the color. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element).
You might be

1. Using the svg as an image, in which case you can't change the color.
2. The !important css keyword should be spaced from the property.