# Fail to replace SVG + JS with SVG files directly, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, font-awesome

My website uses Font Awesome SVG icons via [SVG + JS method](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself#using-svg). Now to improve the performance, I want to use the icons via loading the individual SVG files directly.

I study the code where the icon is inserted:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
```

To my understanding, the JS is just searching the whole DOM and replace the above code with the actual SVG data with style, so I run Chrome DevTools and then inspect the icon, and get the following codes for it:

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-facebook-f fa-w-10" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook-f" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"></path></svg>
```

Now I'll do that manually instead of letting JS to do the task, so I find the styles for classes svg-inline--fa and fa-w-10(it seems that there are no styles for class fa-facebook-f), then add the following CSS code to style.css:

```
.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-10 {
    width: .625em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    vertical-align: -.125em;
}

path { fill: currentColor; }

.facebook-icon {
  background: url(/images/icons/facebook-f.svg);
}

.facebook-icon1 {
  background-image: url(/images/icons/facebook-f.svg);
}

.facebook-icon2 {
  background-image: url(/images/icons/facebook-f1.svg);
}
```

After that, I embed the icons to my web page, as below:

```
<div class="float-social">
  <ul>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><i class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10 facebook-icon"></i></a></li>   
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10 facebook-icon1"></span></a></li>   
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#">
        <img class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10" src="/images/icons/facebook-f1.svg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10 facebook-icon2"></span></a></li>  
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/icons/facebook-f1.svg" class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10"></object></a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <use xlink:href="/images/icons/facebook-f2.svg#example"></use>
          </svg></a></li>     
  </ul>
</div>
```

I try different methods, the first one is the original icon that loaded via SVG + JS, the remaining are my tests, but none of 5 icons looks same as the original one:
[image]

Why?

**Update**

The actual code is on http://www.sybase-recovery.com/, in the left side bar you can see 7 facebook icons.

I try to create a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alanccw/y95swck6/9/, but it seems only the first icon will show. Don't know why?

**Update 2**

After studying the difference between the embedded SVG generated by JS and the individual SVG file, I find there is a **fill="currentColor"** attribute which should be used to control the color of the SVG icon.

So I make another two tests:

1. Create a new SVG icon with the attribute **fill="currentColor"** preset. The new SVG icon is at http://www.sybase-recovery.com/images/icons/facebook-f1.svg. But that not working. See my implementations 4, 5 and 6.
2. I try to follow the instructions in [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element) to add the following in CSS, but still not working:

```
path { fill: currentColor; }
```

**Update 3**

I added the 7th implementation: Change the svg file to add  and get the new one which is actually a SVG sprite http://www.sybase-recovery.com/images/icons/facebook-f2.svg

Then use the following codes:

```
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#"><svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <use xlink:href="/images/icons/facebook-f2.svg#example"></use>
          </svg></a></li>
```

And now this implementation works.

However, I have more questions:

1. Why the following implementation does not work even I add fill="currentColor" to the SVG icon?

```
<span class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10 facebook-icon2"></span>
```

2. Though the 7th implemenation works, it has many disadvantages:

1. I need to modify each SVG icon and convert it to SVG sprite.
2. The code snippet used in the HTML is rather large and I need to copy some of the properties, including the viewbox, otherwise, it will not working.

Comment: can you make that in a fiddle?

Comment: @Viira, I update the post to include the origin website as well as the jsfiddle code.

Comment: I have posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the colour that `currentColor` becomes is based on the value of the `color` property inherited from the parent element.

However you are using an `<img>` element. An `<img>` element is a *replaced element*, and replaced elements do not inherit the styles from their parent document. If it helps, you can think of replaced elements as if they are a thumbnail image of another document that is placed inside the parent document.  For more information, check out this article on [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element).

Comment: Thank you. But one of my implementation is just use the <img> tag but that still not working.

Comment: @alancc and that's because what was just explained to you. You have `<path fill="currentColor"` in your SVG - but because the SVG is embedded via `img`, there _is_ no "current color" that this could refer to, and so you just get black as fallback. You can only format elements inside the SVG via your page's stylsheet, if you write the SVG content directly into your document - `<svg><path ...></svg>`, _not_ when you embed it via `img`

Comment: @CBroe, Sorry for my mistake. I understand Paul explain why <img> does not work. But how to let currentColor work for an external SVG image? I cannot use embedded SVG since it will not be cached.

Comment: @CBroe, Also why other implementations that uses <i>, <span> does not work?

Comment: *But how to let currentColor work for an external SVG image*. You can't. It's not possible.

Comment: *Also why other implementations that uses <i>, <span> does not work?*. Perhaps the SVG file is not loading due to an HTTP error. Look at the network tab in the browser developer tools (press F12).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, The SVG file should be loaded, otherwise, the black "F" will not show. It is just not rendered in the proper color.

Comment: True. I was referring more to the jsfiddle you posted, which has missing icons. The black "f" problem has already been explained.