# svg: styling a path within <use>

Tags: css, svg, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use CSS to style the `fill` of a specific `<path>` within a `<symbol>`.  I've assigned `fill:inherit` to the path in the symbol `<defs>` and I can query the `<use>` instances of the symbol within the SVG DOM, but I can't seem to access that path within these instances.  I looked into `inherit` for the CSS and `currentColor` for the fill of the `<path>` but no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <style>
      symbol#DateCard path.purple {
        fill:inherit;
      }
      use[*|href="#DateCard"] path.purple{
        fill:#ff0095;
        transition:fill .6s; 
      }
      use[*|href="#DateCard"] path.purple:hover{
        path:#ff0000;
      }
    </style>
    <symbol id="DateCard">
      <path class="purple" fill="currentColor" d="..."/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#DateCard"/>
<svg>
```

I can query the path within symbol, but when I query the specific paths within a `<use>` instance, this returns an empty NodeList:

`document.querySelectorAll('use[*|href="#DateCard"] path.purple')`

Comment: There is no way to access the shadow DOM of a Use element.

Comment: I was trying to read this article, https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/, and I was hoping there would be a way, and I'm just not fully understanding it.

Comment: You can use the inherit / currentColor trick to style use elements, but if I remember correctly, you can't target subelements of the use element, you can only set things like fill and stroke colors for the entire use element. And just to emphasize, the SVG shadowDOM is not accessible to JavaScript (yet at least to the best of my knowledge) - so querySelector is not going to work on subelements of the symbol/use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styling inside the shadow DOM needs to be done inside the shadow DOM.

What I learned from [Styling SVG  Content with CSS | Codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) is that CSS variables are very useful in this case. So, here I created different ways of styling: using a style attribute and style element inside the symbol in combination with CSS variables from the "outside" of the symbol.

```css
.card1 {
  --path1-color: #0099CC;
  --path2-color: #FFDF34;
}

.card2 {
  --path1-color: #00008B;
  --path2-color: #FF8C00;
}

.card2:hover {
  --path1-color: #00BFFF;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="400">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="DateCard">
      <style>
        .path2 {
          fill: var(--path2-color);
          transition: fill 1s;
        }
        .path2:hover {
          fill: #800000;
        }
      </style>
      <path class="path1" style="fill: var(--path1-color);transition: fill .6s;" d="M20 40 a 20 20 0 1 1 1 0"/>
      <path class="path2" d="M40 60 a 20 20 0 1 1 1 0"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use href="#DateCard" class="card1"/>
  <use href="#DateCard" class="card2" transform="translate(80 0)"/>
<svg>
```

### Update

OP ask if the hover effect can be achieved using attributes in SVG. An alternative to the :hover pseudo class would be an animation started by the mouse entering and leaving the animated element. Unfortunately it is not as flexible as CSS -- it is difficult to style `<animate>`.

Here is an example on animating the second `<path>` in the symbol:

```css
.card1 {
  --path1-color: #0099CC;
  --path2-color: #FFDF34;
}

.card2 {
  --path1-color: #00008B;
  --path2-color: #FF8C00;
}

.card2:hover {
  --path1-color: #00BFFF;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="400">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="DateCard">
      <style>
        .path2 {
          fill: var(--path2-color);
        }
      </style>
      <path class="path1" style="fill: var(--path1-color);transition: fill .6s;" d="M20 40 a 20 20 0 1 1 1 0"/>
      <path class="path2" d="M40 60 a 20 20 0 1 1 1 0">
        <animate attributeName="fill" dur="1s" values="#FF8C00;#800000" begin="mouseenter" fill="freeze" />
        <animate attributeName="fill" dur="1s" from="#800000" to="#FF8C00" begin="mouseleave" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use href="#DateCard" class="card1"/>
  <use href="#DateCard" class="card2" transform="translate(80 0)"/>
<svg>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.  I'm also wondering what attribute to use in the :hover pseudo class for a CSS transition.

Comment: @itsmikem I made a second example in my answer, trying to answer your question :-)