# How do I get the fill property to work on an svg?

Tags: html, css

A div with an `img` containing the svg

```
<div class="expand-button" onclick="toggleExpand()">
    <img src="Resources/iconmonstr-arrow-65.svg" alt="arrow">
</div>
```

I've tried using the svg as the background `background: url('Resources/iconmonstr-arrow-65.svg')` and using `fill: white;`

Also tried `fill: white !important;`
but, it doesn't seem to be working.

what am I missing?

Comment: You can't alter an SVG that is held in a file in this way. If you need to alter the color dynamically then put the SVG inline. If you need it just the once then alter the file version.

Comment: Also discussed in detail here: [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element?r=SearchResults&s=2|167.5468).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the `.svg` file, try adding the `fill` attribute to it. As an example: `<svg fill="white"`

As I understand from what you are trying to do, you are setting an image with SVG properties, such as `fill`, however this must be done directly to the SVG itself.
Here is another example of a plain circle outline, filled with red.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="red" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle></svg>
```

For any other reasons, consider replacing `<img src="Resources/iconmonstr-arrow-65.svg" alt="arrow">` simply with the svg itself - although its not the most ideal method, such as:

```
<div class="expand-button" onclick="toggleExpand()">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="red" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle></svg>
</div>
```