# In a svg shape divider fill with a background image

Tags: html, css, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/4n7j5a1t/

I'm using a svg shape divider but how I can change the background color to a background image in the fill CSS property ?

```
<svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M600,112.77C268.63,112.77,0,65.52,0,7.23V120H1200V7.23C1200,65.52,931.37,112.77,600,112.77Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
</svg>
```

This is what I have tried so far but it does not keep the svg shape in place (wave):

```
<svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
          <pattern id="imgpattern" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
            <image width="120" height="250"
                   xlink:href="https://example.com/slider-bg.png"/>
          </pattern>
      </defs>
    <path d="M600,112.77C268.63,112.77,0,65.52,0,7.23V120H1200V7.23C1200,65.52,931.37,112.77,600,112.77Z" class="shape-fill" fill="url(#imgpattern)"></path>
</svg>
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element

Comment: What's your goal? Can you explain it a bit more clear?

Comment: @Frizzant the goal is to fill the black background with an image.

Comment: I think you could manage that with css  `mask`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
You have to define the image and then add it as a fill.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted but I hope it helps. If not try to explain a little more and I might be able to help you.

Cheers!

```html
<svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450">
            <image xlink:href="https://image.api.playstation.com/vulcan/img/rnd/202011/0714/vuF88yWPSnDfmFJVTyNJpVwW.png" x="0" y="0"
                width="600" height="450" /><!-- Image from http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile/6-grass-meadow-tile.php-->
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path fill="url(#img1")" d="M600,112.77C268.63,112.77,0,65.52,0,7.23V120H1200V7.23C1200,65.52,931.37,112.77,600,112.77Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
    
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your support. What I want is to fill the black background color. Hope it helps to understand more the issue.