# How to change color of this SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

I've tried multiple methods of changing this SVG's color but I cannot find a solution.

Thank you in advance, it's really appreciated!

```html
<svg width="30" height="42" viewBox="0 0 30 42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect width="30" height="42" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(-0.327273) scale(0.0212121 0.0151515)"/>
    </pattern>
    <image id="image0" width="78" height="66" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: it's filled with image, you would have to link different image

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the png or just the area surrounding the png?

Comment: @jdweng the whole svg

Comment: You have an image inside rectangle which is inside the view box.  So what are you changing?

Comment: You  image is larger than the rectangle and viewbox so changing the rectangle and viewbox will not show due to the image being larger.

Comment: @jdweng it's being scaled to ~20% and used as a pattern

Comment: @Mortiz you can use for example a free application - Inkscape to edit the svg

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after hours of googling and researching, I decoded the base64 png manually and converted it to a PNG file. Thereafter I changed the color of the PNG, to save it and encode it back again.

I would totally recommend this solution for anyone struggling with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors by css filter.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

svg image {
  filter: invert(0.75) sepia(1) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(1000%);
}

.fontAwesome {
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="30" height="42" viewBox="0 0 30 42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect width="30" height="42" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(-0.327273) scale(0.0212121 0.0151515)"/>
    </pattern>
    <image id="image0" width="78" height="66" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
  </defs>
</svg>

<p class="fontAwesome slider-h">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="sliders-h" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-sliders-h fa-w-16 fa-3x"><path fill="currentColor" d="M496 384H160v-16c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16h-32c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v16H16c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v32c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h80v16c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-16h336c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-32c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm0-160h-80v-16c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16h-32c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v16H16c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v32c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h336v16c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-16h80c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-32c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm0-160H288V48c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16h-32c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16v16H16C7.2 64 0 71.2 0 80v32c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h208v16c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-16h208c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V80c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16z" class=""></path>
  
</svg>

</p>
```

Better use vector icon libraries like fontAwesome, feather icons etc.
They offer a superior quality in any size and can be colored by fill or color attribute.

See also:

[How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element)