# how to set or change color SVG icon in img tag - css?

Tags: css, svg

As I expected, this question was asked a lot, but I did not find the answer to any of the questions, and no one gave exactly the answer I wanted.

I want to change or set the color of the `svg` in img tag!

Please guide me with its description. I want to solve my problem by using a CSS!

```css
.container_image {
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px dashed #ddd;
   margin: 1rem auto;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
 
 .container_image > img {
    color: #333;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="container_image">
        <img src="svg_name.svg">
    </div>
```

Comment: you can not set color for svg icon in img tag :(

Comment: If you've seen answers and none are exactly what you want then you need to explain why those answers don't suit and also show you understand the limitations of img tags and cross-document styling, otherwise we're just going to duplicate this like we do all the others. Or maybe the answer **you can't** would suit?

Comment: You can **not** style SVG in an IMG tag with CSS <period> There are plenty of workarounds listed in the answers you link to, I [added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element/70986923#70986923) a 2022 using a Web Component answer in one recently