# Make svg file change colours on hover on select menu

Tags: css, svg, sass

I have seen this post below and it does not help, I read it top to bottom and still don't understand [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element) There are many competing answers, none of which look like what I'm doing.. and perhaps it does if you understood it more.. but I don't, which is the reason I came to this site. I would be very appreciative if someone could translate my codepen into one of those answers in a clear concise way.

I have a select menu which uses a svg graphic for the open arrow. It has been requested that on hover  of the select I make the svg turn green and get slightly bolder. I have tried changing the background url property by adding a colour with no luck as I have read on other threads, but that just changes my select menu to green. How can I just change the svg arrow colour and make it bolder (if even possible)?

I created a codepen
https://codepen.io/justinblayney/pen/PoENamE

I tried adding another graphic, but that doesn't always load in time and we don't want to preload it.

here is my scss

```
  .find-an-option {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    
    select::-ms-expand,
      .select:after {
        display: none;
        content: "";
      }

      select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/djk8wzpz4/image/upload/v1647694948/path-arrow_wloczn.svg") center right
          30px no-repeat;
        border: white 2px solid;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
        border-radius: 7px;
        font: normal normal bold 16px/18px Arial;
        padding: 0px 25px;
        &:hover {
          border: #242b44 2px solid;
          background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/djk8wzpz4/image/upload/v1647694948/path-arrow_wloczn.svg") center
            right 30px no-repeat;
          background-color: white;
        }
      }
    
}
```

here is my html

```
  <form class="find-an-option">
        <select id="games" name="games" class="">
            <option value="" selected>Games</option>
            <option value="" selected>option 1</option>
           <option value="" selected>option 2</option>
        </select>
       
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the fill or stroke color of an `background-image`.

But you could easily use 2 svgs inlined as data-URLs [(converted by Yoksel's converting tool)](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder):

```css
.find-an-option {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.find-an-option select::-ms-expand,
.find-an-option .select:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
}
.find-an-option select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20.4 11.2' %3E%3Cpath  d='M1.5,1.5l8.2,8.2l9.1-8.2' style='fill:none;stroke:%23242B44;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center right 30px no-repeat;
  border: white 2px solid;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font: normal normal bold 16px/18px Arial;
  padding: 0px 25px;
}
.find-an-option select:hover {
  border: #242b44 2px solid;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20.4 11.2' %3E%3Cpath  d='M1.5,1.5l8.2,8.2l9.1-8.2' style='fill:none;stroke:green;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center right 30px no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
  <form class="find-an-option">
        <select id="games" name="games" class="">
            <option value="" selected>Games</option>
            <option value="" selected>option 1</option>
           <option value="" selected>option 2</option>
        </select>       
</form>
```

Since your arrow/chevron icon is rather small the additional css "bloat" should be negligible.