# Having trouble controlling svg style from outside

Tags: html, css, svg, fill

I'm trying to set `fill` and `stroke` to an .svg file which I refer on my .html file through `<img>`.

I am able to change it the way I want with no problem as long as it is an inline `<svg>` but not an `<img>`.

I read here in a question that deleting the hardcoded `fill`/`stroke` should make my css take effect but it doesn't.

What can I do with css?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c230ptyh/49/) with all relevant code.

Comment: Global CSS can't style IMG content

Comment: What are my options then? This is the logo, so I think it is better as an `<img>`  with `alt=` and all other properties and behaviors.

Comment: @XanderTEM your only option is to include the `<svg>...</svg>` in your code -- why would you need an alt tag if the SVG is inline? It will never fail to load

Comment: Unless you want to use CSS filters, then refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element

Comment: Since your SVG files are external (because you load them in an IMG tag); load the SVG source using a native Web Component; and inline them; with the added bonus to _scope_ your CSS in a shadowDOM; [see this Dev.to blog post I wrote](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)