# How to replace an arrow icon into a red colored SVG image

Tags: html, css, svg

So actually, I use boxicons to display an arrow icon.

```
<ul class="nav-links">
   <li >
      <a class="item" >
      <i></i>
      <span class="links_name">Portfolio</span>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="submenu" #submenu></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I would like the arrow to be red, so I downloaded the icon and changed the image to red using an image editor.

Here is the code SVM

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="288" height="288">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="288" height="288" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="#ff3e2b" id="arrow" d="M16.293 9.293 12 13.586 7.707 9.293l-1.414 1.414L12 16.414l5.707-5.707z" class="color000 svgShape"/>
   </svg>
</svg>
```

I don't know where I have to include #arrow in CSS ? I think the class `fa-chevron-down` should be deleted but I'm not sure where/how to add `#arrow`

Thank you in advance for your help.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #0a2558;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active {
  width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .logo-details i {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name img {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a.active {
  background: #081d45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
  background: #081d45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .submenu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #239cd3;
  transition: height 0.4s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .submenu a:hover {
  background: #198ac1;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .submenu .links_subname {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .log_out {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active ~ .home-section {
  width: calc(100% - -30px);
  left: -30px;
}

.home-section nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.active ~ .home-section nav {
  left: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
}

.home-section nav .sidebar-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

nav .sidebar-button i {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.home-section nav .search-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

nav .search-box input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  background: #f5f6fa;
  border: 2px solid #efeef1;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

nav .search-box .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #2697ff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4 ease;
}

.home-section .home-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 104px;
}

.home-content .overview-boxes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.overview-boxes .box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(100% / 4 - 15px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 14px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.overview-boxes .box-topic {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.home-content .box .number {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.home-content .box .indicator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.home-content .box .indicator i {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #8fdacb;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.box .indicator i.down {
  background: #e87d88;
}

.home-content .box .indicator .text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.home-content .box .cart {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #cce5ff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #66b0ff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: -15px 0 0 6px;
}

.home-content .box .cart.two {
  color: #2bd47d;
  background: #c0f2d8;
}

.home-content .box .cart.three {
  color: #ffc233;
  background: #ffe8b3;
}

.home-content .box .cart.four {
  color: #e05260;
  background: #f7d4d7;
}

.home-content .total-order {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.home-content .sales-boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* padding: 0 20px; */
}

/* left box */

.home-content .sales-boxes .recent-sales {
  width: 65%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.home-content .sales-boxes .sales-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.sales-boxes .box .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
}

.sales-boxes .sales-details li.topic {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.sales-boxes .sales-details li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.sales-boxes .sales-details li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sales-boxes .box .button {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sales-boxes .box .button a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0a2558;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sales-boxes .box .button a:hover {
  background: #0d3073;
}

/* Right box */

.home-content .sales-boxes .top-sales {
  width: 35%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sales-boxes .top-sales li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.sales-boxes .top-sales li a img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.sales-boxes .top-sales li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sales-boxes .top-sales li .product,
.price {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
}

.menu-summary-container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-summary-container .user,
.menu-summary-container .last-connection {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar" >
    <div class="logo-details">
      <span class="logo_name">
        <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/30/27uw.png" />
      </span>
    </div>
  
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li >
          <a class="item" >
            <i></i>
            <span class="links_name">Portfolio</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="submenu" #submenu></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
    <nav>
      <div class="sidebar-button">
        <i class="sidebarBtn"></i>
      </div>
  
      <div class="menu-summary-container">
        <span class="user">User: </span>
        <span class="last-connection">last connection: </span>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </section>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing different icon libraries.
If you need to use boxicons you should delete fontAwesome elements like:

```
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
```

Either replace this element with the svg directly:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  background: #0a2558;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.svgItem {
  height: 1.3em;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.color000 {
  color: red
}

.box-icon {
  fill: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a class="item">
          <span class="links_name">Portfolio</span>
          <svg class="svgItem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" id="arrow" d="M16.293 9.293 12 13.586 7.707 9.293l-1.414 1.414L12 16.414l5.707-5.707z" class="color000 svgShape"/>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu" #submenu></ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a>Rocket <box-icon class="box-icon" name="chevron-down"></box-icon></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Or use the **web component** approach [described here](https://boxicons.com/usage)

```
<box-icon class="box-icon" name="chevron-down"></box-icon>
```

If you're using the svg icon as an inlined element, you would change the icon color via `fill` attribute.

```
path{fill:red}
```

It's recommended to strip the fill attribute in your svg markup to avoid unnecessary high specificity.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M16.293 9.293 12 13.586 7.707 9.293l-1.414 1.414L12 16.414l5.707-5.707z" />
</svg>
```

However you can make a path inherit a font/text color by using the `currentColor` keyword:

```
path{color: red}   


<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="currentColor" d="M16.293 9.293 12 13.586 7.707 9.293l-1.414 1.414L12 16.414l5.707-5.707z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot herrstrietzel for your explanations. My problem is solved, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
i.fa.fa-chevron-down{
  color: red!important;
}
```

If you don't mind adding !important attribute, this is how you can perform the action with CSS only

Comment: Thanks for your help, I need to use an svg image.

Comment: You might check this (sorry to be the guy to reference you to a link): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element#:~:text=To%20simply%20change%20the%20color,mention%20the%20color%20in%20fill.