# Access encapsulated component of <object> element in HTML for styling in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm importing an svg from file using the `<object>` element

```html
<object data="img/icons/some-svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

From the inspect element tool it's hierarchy appears as follows in the browser

```html
<object data="img/icons/some-svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
   #document
   <svg ...>
   ...
   </svg>
</object>
```

As I want to change the color of the svg how do I access the encapsulated svg component in the object element?

Comment: You can't use (global) styles to style content **inside** ``img`` or ``object``. One way around this is to load the _external_ content and **inject** it into the DOM. See SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element/70986923#70986923

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you insert a style into a document. The rect element has no colour defined in markup, the green colour comes from the javascript injected style rule.

```js
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('rect { fill: green; }', 0);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="100" height="100"/></svg>
```

So now we know how to do that how do we use it with an object tag. Well we need to get the object tag. You could either give it an id and get it by its id or try to find it in the DOM e.g.

```
let o = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
```

Then you get its [contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/contentDocument) i.e.

```
let doc = o.contentDocument;
```

and you can use that to insert the style as demonstrated above. I.e.

```
doc.styleSheets[0].insertRule('rect { fill: green; }', 0);
```

Unfortunately I can't demonstrate this from start to finish because the contentDocument of a data url is null.

Answer (score -1):

```
svg {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

use this css rule to change the color

Comment: I think the point is to explain how you're going to get that into the object element's contents.