# Manipulating path tag in SVG image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to fill the color of certain paths in my SVG image. Here is a snippet of the SVG itself.

```
<svg baseprofile="tiny" fill="#ececec" height="857" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".2" version="1.2" viewbox="0 0 2000 857" width="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M1383 261.6l1.5 1.8-2.9 0.8-2.4 1.1-5.9 0.8-5.3 1.3-2.4 2.8 1.9 2.7 1.4 3.2-2 2.7 0.8 2.5-0.9 2.3-5.2-0.2 3.1 4.2-3.1 1.7-1.4 3.8 1.1 3.9-1.8 1.8-2.1-0.6-4 0.9-0.2 1.7-4.1 0-2.3 3.7 0.8 5.4-6.6 2.7-3.9-0.6-0.9 1.4-3.4-0.8-5.3 1-9.6-3.3 3.9-5.8-1.1-4.1-4.3-1.1-1.2-4.1-2.7-5.1 1.6-3.5-2.5-1 0.5-4.7 0.6-8 5.9 2.5 3.9-0.9 0.4-2.9 4-0.9 2.6-2-0.2-5.1 4.2-1.3 0.3-2.2 2.9 1.7 1.6 0.2 3 0 4.3 1.4 1.8 0.7 3.4-2 2.1 1.2 0.9-2.9 3.2 0.1 0.6-0.9-0.2-2.6 1.7-2.2 3.3 1.4-0.1 2 1.7 0.3 0.9 5.4 2.7 2.1 1.5-1.4 2.2-0.6 2.5-2.9 3.8 0.5 5.4 0z" id="AF" name="Afghanistan">
 </path>
 <path class="Angola" d="M 1121.2 572 1121.8 574 1121.1 577.1 1122 580.1 1121.1 582.5 1121.5 584.7 1109.8 584.6 1109 605.1 1112.6 610.3 1116.2 614.3 1105.8 616.9 1092.3 616 1088.5 613 1065.8 613.2 1065 613.7 1061.7 610.8 1058.1 610.6 1054.7 611.7 1052 612.9 1051.5 608.9 1052.4 603.2 1054.4 597.3 1054.7 594.6 1056.6 588.8 1058 586.2 1061.3 582 1063.2 579.1 1063.8 574.4 1063.5 570.7 1061.9 568.4 1060.4 564.5 1059.1 560.7 1059.4 559.3 1061.1 556.8 1059.5 550.6 1058.3 546.3 1055.5 542.2 1056.1 541 1058.4 540.1 1060.1 540.2 1062.1 539.5 1078.8 539.6 1080.1 544.3 1081.7 548.2 1083 550.3 1085.1 553.6 1088.9 553.1 1090.7 552.2 1093.8 553.1 1094.7 551.5 1096.2 547.8 1099.7 547.5 1100 546.4 1102.9 546.4 1102.4 548.7 1109.2 548.6 1109.3 552.7 1110.4 555.1 1109.5 559 1109.9 563 1111.7 565.4 1111.3 573 1112.7 572.4 1115.1 572.6 1118.6 571.6 1121.2 572 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Angola" d="M 1055.3 539 1053.8 534.2 1056.1 531.4 1057.8 530.3 1059.9 532.5 1057.9 533.9 1056.9 535.5 1056.7 538.3 1055.3 539 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1088 228l0.4 1.2 1.4-0.6 1.2 1.7 1.3 0.7 0.6 2.3-0.5 2.2 1 2.7 2.3 1.5 0.1 1.7-1.7 0.9-0.1 2.1-2.2 3.1-0.9-0.4-0.2-1.4-3.1-2.2-0.7-3 0.1-4.4 0.5-1.9-0.9-1-0.5-2.1 1.9-3.1z" id="AL" name="Albania">
 </path>
 <path d="M1296.2 336.7l1.3 5.1-2.8 0 0 4.2 1.1 0.9-2.4 1.3 0.2 2.6-1.3 2.6 0 2.6-1 1.4-16.9-3.2-2.7-6.6-0.3-1.4 0.9-0.4 0.4 1.8 4.2-1 4.6 0.2 3.4 0.2 3.3-4.4 3.7-4.1 3-4 1.3 2.2z" id="AE" name="United Arab Emirates">
 </path>
 <path class="Argentina" d="M 669.1 851.7 666.1 851.5 661.1 851.5 655.1 837.9 658.2 840.7 662.5 845.3 670.3 849 677.6 850.5 676.8 853.5 672.4 853.8 669.1 851.7 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Argentina" d="M 638.6 644.7 649.9 655.1 654.5 656.1 661.8 660.9 667.7 663.4 668.8 666.2 664.6 676 670.4 677.7 676.7 678.7 680.9 677.7 685.2 672.7 685.5 667.1 688.1 665.8 691.3 669.6 691.7 674.7 687.5 678.2 684.2 680.8 678.9 687.1 672.9 695.8 672.4 701 672 707.6 673.2 714 672.3 715.4 672.7 719.5 673 722.9 680.8 728.4 681 732.8 684.9 735.6 685.2 738.7 681.9 746.9 674.9 750.4 664.7 751.7 658.7 751 660.8 754.9 660.9 759.6 662.7 762.8 660.2 765.1 655.1 766 649.5 763.6 648 765.3 650.5 771.6 654.5 773.5 656.8 771.5 659.3 774.8 655.1 776.8 652.2 780.8 653.4 787.1 653.3 790.5 648.5 790.5 645.5 793.7 645.6 798.5 652.1 803.1 657.3 804.3 657.5 810 652.9 813.5 652.3 820.8 648.8 823.2 647.9 826.1 652.1 832.6 656.7 836.1 654.6 835.8 649.7 834.8 637.6 834 634.1 830.4 632.2 825.8 629.1 826.2 626.5 823.9 623.4 817.4 626.1 814.6 626.2 810.7 624.4 807.5 625.1 802.1 624 793.8 622.2 790.1 624 788.9 622.6 786.5 619.8 785.3 620.6 782.6 617.5 780.2 613.8 772.9 615.5 771.6 612.2 763.8 611.4 757.3 611.2 751.6 613.7 749.3 610.4 743 608.8 737.2 611.8 733 610.4 727.6 612 721.4 610.6 715.5 609 714.3 604.1 703.2 606.2 696.6 604.5 690.4 605.4 684.5 608 678.5 611.3 674.5 609.3 672 610.1 669.9 608.5 659.2 614.1 656.1 615.3 649.4 614.4 647.8 618.4 642 625.9 643.6 629.6 648.2 631.2 643 637.6 643.3 638.6 644.7 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1230.8 253l-1.8 0.2-2.8-3.7-0.2-1-2.3 0-1.9-1.7-1 0.1-2.4-1.8-4.2-1.6-0.1-3.1-1.3-2.2 7-1 1.4 1.6 2.2 1.1-0.7 1.6 3.2 2.2-1.1 2.1 2.6 1.7 2.5 1 0.9 4.5z" id="AM" name="Armenia">
 </path>
 <path class="Australia" d="M 1743 763.6 1746.7 765.8 1750 764.9 1754.9 763.7 1757.7 764.1 1753.2 771.7 1749.9 773.8 1745.9 779 1745.3 777.2 1738.7 781.6 1737.9 781.3 1734.9 781.1 1735.4 775.7 1737.4 771.5 1738 765.9 1740 763 1743 763.6 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Australia" d="M 1793.5 590.2 1794.7 595.2 1798.7 592.8 1800.1 595.5 1802.4 598 1801.3 600.9 1801.5 606.4 1801.7 609.6 1803 610.4 1803.4 615.9 1802.2 619.2 1803 623.5 1808.4 626.9 1811.6 629.9 1814.8 632.7 1813.7 634.3 1816 638.3 1816.5 645.3 1819.1 643.9 1820.6 646.6 1822.2 645.7 1821.5 652.5 1824.4 656.4 1826.3 658.8 1829.1 664 1829.1 669.2 1828.1 672.9 1826.3 676.8 1827 682.3 1824.5 688 1822.4 691 1818.6 696.7 1817.1 700.4 1814 705 1809 710.8 1803.5 714 1799.1 718.9 1795.8 722.1 1791.4 727.6 1787.7 730.8 1783.8 735.6 1780.7 740 1779.9 742.1 1775.6 744.3 1769.5 744.5 1763.2 747.2 1759.4 749.6 1754.6 752.4 1751.9 749.5 1749.3 748.4 1751.9 745.1 1748.4 746.3 1741.2 750.9 1737.6 749.2 1735.2 748.2 1732.4 747.7 1728.3 745.9 1727 741.9 1728.5 737.1 1728.9 733.8 1727.5 731.2 1722.8 730.5 1726 727.3 1726.9 722.6 1722.2 727 1716.9 728.2 1721.4 724.7 1723.9 721 1727.4 717.8 1729 713.1 1722.2 718.5 1717.9 720.7 1713.6 725.8 1710.6 723.2 1712.3 719.8 1710.9 715.1 1709.1 712.7 1710.7 711.2 1705.4 707.3 1701.6 707.2 1697.6 704 1687.7 704.6 1679.8 706.9 1672.9 709.1 1667.9 708.7 1660.9 712 1655.6 713.4 1653.3 716.8 1650.3 719.4 1645.6 719.6 1642 720.1 1637.8 719 1633.6 719.7 1629.8 720 1625.3 723.4 1623.8 723.1 1620.4 724.9 1617 726.9 1613.2 726.7 1609.7 726.7 1605.6 722.6 1603.2 721.4 1604.7 717.7 1607.6 716.8 1609.1 715.4 1609.7 713.1 1612 708.6 1612.7 704.8 1612 698.3 1612.2 694.6 1613.6 691 1612.7 686.8 1613 684.9 1611.3 682.3 1612 677.3 1610.1 672.2 1610 669.5 1611.8 672.3 1611.3 666.3 1613.6 668.2 1614.7 670.7 1615.3 667.4 1613.7 662.3 1613.6 660.3 1612.8 658.4 1614.1 654.7 1615.6 653.1 1616.9 649.9 1617 646.1 1620.1 641.5 1619.7 646.4 1622.8 642 1627.7 639.8 1630.9 637.1 1635.6 634.7 1638.2 634.2 1639.6 635 1644.4 632.6 1647.9 631.9 1649 630.5 1650.5 629.9 1653.6 630.1 1659.8 628.2 1663.3 625.3 1665.3 621.9 1669.2 618.7 1669.9 616.1 1670.6 612.6 1675.5 607.1 1676.9 612.7 1679.5 611.4 1678 608.4 1680.3 605.3 1682.5 606.7 1684 601.8 1687.5 598.6 1689.3 596.1 1692.2 595 1692.6 593.2 1694.9 593.9 1695.3 592.3 1697.9 591.4 1700.7 590.5 1704.4 593.5 1707 597.3 1710.5 597.3 1714 597.9 1713.3 594.4 1716.8 589.3 1719.5 587.6 1718.9 586 1721.8 582.3 1725.5 580 1728.2 580.8 1733.1 579.6 1733.4 576.3 1729.5 574.2 1732.6 573.3 1736.2 574.9 1738.9 577.5 1743.4 579.1 1745.1 578.5 1748.4 580.5 1751.9 578.6 1753.9 579.2 1755.4 577.9 1757.6 581.1 1755.6 584.6 1753.1 587.2 1751.2 587.4 1751.5 589.9 1749.3 593.1 1746.8 596.3 1747 598.1 1750.8 601.7 1754.8 603.7 1757.3 605.9 1760.6 609.7 1762.2 609.7 1764.8 611.4 1765.3 613.4 1770.2 615.5 1774.3 613.3 1776.1 609.9 1777.8 607 1779.1 603.5 1781.7 598.4 1781.5 595.3 1782.2 593.4 1782.1 589.8 1783.5 584.9 1784.8 583.6 1784.2 581.5 1786 578.1 1787.5 574.6 1787.9 572.7 1790.2 570.3 1791.5 573.5 1791.4 577.5 1792.7 578.3 1792.6 581 1794.2 584.2 1794.1 587.9 1793.5 590.2 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1070.6 190.8l-0.3 0.8 0.7 2.1-0.2 2.6-2.8 0 1.1 1.4-1.3 4-0.9 1.1-4.4 0.1-2.4 1.5-4.2-0.5-7.3-1.7-1.3-2.1-4.9 1.1-0.5 1.2-3.1-0.9-2.6-0.2-2.3-1.2 0.7-1.5-0.2-1.1 1.4-0.3 2.7 1.7 0.6-1.7 4.4 0.3 3.5-1.1 2.4 0.2 1.7 1.3 0.4-1.1-1-4.1 1.7-0.8 1.6-2.9 3.8 2.1 2.6-2.6 1.7-0.5 4 1.9 2.3-0.3 2.4 1.2z" id="AT" name="Austria">
 </path>
 <path class="Azerbaijan" d="M 1229 253.2 1225.2 252.3 1222 249.4 1220.8 246.9 1221.8 246.8 1223.7 248.5 1226 248.5 1226.2 249.5 1229 253.2 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Azerbaijan" d="M 1235.3 236.2 1237.8 233.6 1241.3 236.9 1244.9 241.5 1247.4 241.8 1249.3 243.5 1245.1 244 1245.2 249 1244.8 251.2 1243.1 252.7 1243.9 255.8 1242.6 256.2 1238.7 252.8 1239.9 249.7 1238 247.8 1236.1 248.3 1230.8 253 1229.9 248.5 1227.4 247.5 1224.8 245.8 1225.9 243.7 1222.7 241.5 1223.4 239.9 1221.2 238.8 1219.8 237.2 1220.9 236.1 1225.1 238 1228 238.3 1228.6 237.6 1225.3 234.1 1226.5 233.3 1228 233.5 1232.3 237.3 1234.7 237.8 1235.3 236.2 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1154.9 530.4l-0.6 0.1 0-0.3-2-6.1-0.01-0.06-0.09-1.04-1.4-2.9 3.5 0.5 1.7-3.7 3.1 0.4 0.3 2.5 1.2 1.5 0 2.1-1.4 1.3-2.3 3.4-2 2.3z" id="BI" name="Burundi">
 </path>
 <path d="M1016.5 177.1l-0.4 4.2-1.3 0.2-0.4 3.5-4.4-2.9-2.5 0.5-3.5-2.9-2.4-2.5-2.2-0.1-0.8-2.2 3.9-1.2 3.6 0.5 4.5-1.3 3.1 2.7 2.8 1.5z" id="BE" name="Belgium">
 </path>
 <path d="M1006.7 427l-0.2 2.1 1.3 3.8-1.1 2.6 0.6 1.7-2.8 4-1.7 2-1.1 4 0.2 4.1-0.3 10.3-4.7 0.8-1.4-4.4 0.3-14.8-1.2-1.3-0.2-3.2-2-2.2-1.7-1.9 0.7-3.4 2-0.7 1.1-2.8 2.8-0.6 1.2-1.9 1.9-1.9 2 0 4.3 3.7z" id="BJ" name="Benin">
 </path>
 <path d="M988.5 406l-0.5 3.1 0.8 2.9 3.1 4.2 0.2 3.1 6.5 1.5-0.1 4.4-1.2 1.9-2.8 0.6-1.1 2.8-2 0.7-4.9-0.1-2.6-0.5-1.8 1-2.5-0.5-9.8 0.3-0.2 3.7 0.8 4.8-3.9-1.6-2.6 0.2-2 1.6-2.5-1.3-1-2.2-2.5-1.4-0.4-3.7 1.6-2.7-0.2-2.2 4.5-5.3 0.9-4.4 1.5-1.6 2.7 0.9 2.4-1.3 0.8-1.7 4.3-2.8 1.1-2 5.3-2.7 3.1-0.9 1.4 1.2 3.6 0z" id="BF" name="Burkina Faso">
 </path>
 <path d="M1500.6 360.3l0.6 4.6-2.1-1 1.1 5.2-2.1-3.3-0.8-3.3-1.5-3.1-2.8-3.7-5.2-0.3 0.9 2.7-1.2 3.5-2.6-1.3-0.6 1.2-1.7-0.7-2.2-0.6-1.6-5.3-2.6-4.8 0.3-3.9-3.7-1.7 0.9-2.3 3-2.4-4.6-3.4 1.2-4.4 4.9 2.8 2.7 0.3 1.2 4.5 5.4 0.9 5.1-0.1 3.4 1.1-1.6 5.4-2.4 0.4-1.2 3.6 3.6 3.4 0.3-4.2 1.5 0 4.4 10.2z" id="BD" name="Bangladesh">
 </path>
 <path d="M1132.6 221.6l-2.3 2.6-1.3 4.5 2.1 3.6-4.6-0.8-5 2 0.3 3.2-4.6 0.6-3.9-2.3-4 1.8-3.8-0.2-0.8-4.2-2.8-2.1 0.7-0.8-0.6-0.8 0.6-2 1.8-2-2.8-2.7-0.7-2.4 1.1-1.4 1.8 2.6 1.9-0.4 4 0.9 7.6 0.4 2.3-1.6 5.9-1.5 4 2.3 3.1 0.7z" id="BG" name="Bulgaria">
 </path>
 <path d="M1083 214.3l1.9-0.1-1.1 2.8 2.7 2.5-0.5 2.9-1.1 0.3-0.9 0.6-1.6 1.5-0.4 3.5-4.8-2.4-2.1-2.7-2.1-1.4-2.5-2.4-1.3-1.9-2.7-3 0.8-2.6 2 1.5 1-1.4 2.3-0.1 4.5 1.1 3.5-0.1 2.4 1.4z" id="BA" name="Bosnia and Herzegovina">
 </path>
 <path d="M1141.6 162.7l-3.9-0.2-0.8 0.6 1.5 2 2 4-4.1 0.3-1.3 1.4 0.3 3.1-2.1-0.6-4.3 0.3-1.5-1.5-1.7 1.1-1.9-0.9-3.9-0.1-5.7-1.5-4.9-0.5-3.8 0.2-2.4 1.6-2.3 0.3-0.5-2.8-1.9-2.8 2.8-1.3-0.4-2.4-1.7-2.3-0.6-2.7 4.7 0 4.8-2.3 0.5-3.4 3.6-2-1-2.7 2.7-1 4.6-2.3 5.3 1.5 0.9 1.5 2.4-0.7 4.8 1.4 1.1 2.9-0.7 1.6 3.8 4 2.1 1.1 0 1.1 3.4 1.1 1.7 1.6-1.6 1.3z" id="BY" name="Belarus">
 </path>
 <path d="M487.8 399.8l-1.7 0 1.3-7.2 0.7-5.1 0.1-1 0.7-0.3 0.9 0.8 2.5-3.9 1.1-0.1-0.1 1 1 0-0.3 1.8-1.3 2.7 0.4 1-0.9 2.3 0.3 0.6-1 3.3-1.3 1.7-1.1 0.2-1.3 2.2z" id="BZ" name="Belize">
 </path>
 <path d="M662.5 631.4l-0.3-2-5.4-3.3-5.2-0.1-9.6 1.9-2.1 5.6 0.2 3.5-1.5 7.7-1-1.4-6.4-0.3-1.6 5.2-3.7-4.6-7.5-1.6-4 5.8-3.9 0.9-3.1-8.9-3.7-7.2 1.1-6.2-3.2-2.7-1.2-4.6-3.2-4.4 2.9-6.9-2.9-5.4 1.1-2.2-1.2-2.4 1.9-3.2-0.3-5.4 0-4.6 1.1-2.1-5.5-10.4 4.2 0.6 2.9-0.2 1.1-1.9 4.8-2.6 2.9-2.4 7.3-1.1-0.4 4.8 0.9 2.5-0.3 4.3 6.5 5.7 6.4 1.1 2.3 2.4 3.9 1.3 2.5 1.8 3.5 0 3.4 1.9 0.5 3.7 1.2 1.9 0.3 2.7-1.7 0.1 2.8 7.5 10.7 0.3-0.5 3.7 0.8 2.5 3.2 1.8 1.7 4-0.6 5.1-1.3 2.8 0.8 3.6-1.6 1.4z" id="BO" name="Bolivia">
 </path>
 <path d="M665.8 489.6l3.1 0.6 0.6-1.4-1-1.2 0.6-1.9 2.3 0.6 2.7-0.7 3.2 1.4 2.5 1.3 1.7-1.7 1.3 0.2 0.8 1.8 2.7-0.4 2.2-2.5 1.8-4.7 3.4-5.9 2-0.3 1.3 3.6 3 11.2 3.1 1.1 0.1 4.4-4.3 5.3 1.7 1.9 10.1 1 0.2 6.5 4.3-4.2 7.1 2.3 9.5 3.9 2.8 3.7-0.9 3.6 6.6-2 11 3.4 8.5-0.2 8.4 5.3 7.4 7.2 4.4 1.8 4.8 0.3 2.1 2 2 8.2 1.1 3.9-2.1 10.6-2.7 4.2-7.7 8.9-3.4 7.3-4 5.5-1.4 0.2-1.3 4.7 0.9 12-1.1 9.9-0.3 4.2-1.6 2.6-0.5 8.6-5.2 8.3-0.5 6.7-4.3 2.7-1.1 3.9-6 0-8.5 2.4-3.7 2.9-6 1.9-6.1 5.1-4.1 6.4-0.3 4.8 1.3 3.5-0.3 6.5-0.8 3.1-3.4 3.6-4.5 11.3-4 5-3.2 3.1-1.5 6.1-2.9 3.6-2.1-3.6 1.8-3.1-3.8-4.3-4.8-3.6-6.3-4.1-1.9 0.2-6.3-5-3.4 0.7 6-8.7 5.3-6.3 3.3-2.6 4.2-3.5-0.4-5.1-3.2-3.8-2.6 1.3 0.7-3.7 0.3-3.8-0.3-3.6-2.1-1.1-2 1-2.1-0.3-0.8-2.4-1.1-5.9-1.2-1.9-3.9-1.8-2.2 1.3-5.9-1.3-0.4-8.7-2-3.5 1.6-1.4-0.8-3.6 1.3-2.8 0.6-5.1-1.7-4-3.2-1.8-0.8-2.5 0.5-3.7-10.7-0.3-2.8-7.5 1.7-0.1-0.3-2.7-1.2-1.9-0.5-3.7-3.4-1.9-3.5 0-2.5-1.8-3.9-1.3-2.3-2.4-6.4-1.1-6.5-5.7 0.3-4.3-0.9-2.5 0.4-4.8-7.3 1.1-2.9 2.4-4.8 2.6-1.1 1.9-2.9 0.2-4.2-0.6-3.2 1.1-2.6-0.7-0.1-9.7-4.4 3.7-5-0.1-2.3-3.5-3.8-0.3 1-2.8-3.3-3.9-2.6-5.8 1.5-1.1-0.2-2.8 3.4-1.8-0.7-3.5 1.4-2.2 0.3-3 6.3-4.4 4.6-1.2 0.8-1 5.1 0.3 2.2-17.6 0.1-2.8-0.9-3.6-2.6-2.4 0.1-4.7 3.2-1 1.1 0.7 0.2-2.5-3.3-0.7 0-4 11 0.2 1.9-2.3 1.6 2.1 1 3.8 1.1-0.8 3.1 3.4 4.4-0.4 1.1-2 4.2-1.5 2.4-1.1 0.7-2.7 4.1-1.8-0.3-1.4-4.8-0.5-0.7-4.1 0.3-4.3-2.5-1.6 1.1-0.6 4.1 0.8 4.5 1.6 1.7-1.5 4.1-1 6.4-2.4 2.1-2.5-0.7-1.8 3-0.2 1.2 1.4-0.8 2.9 2 0.9 1.2 3-1.6 2.3-1 5.4 1.4 3.3 0.3 3 3.5 3 2.8 0.3 0.6-1.3 1.8-0.3 2.6-1.1 1.8-1.7 3.2 0.6 1.3-0.3z" id="BR" name="Brazil">
 </path>
 <path d="M1633.1 472.8l2.2-2.4 4.6-3.6-0.1 3.2-0.1 4.1-2.7-0.2-1.1 2.2-2.8-3.3z" id="BN" name="Brunei Darussalam">
 </path>
```

My goal is to be able to use JS to manipulate the color of the path. For example, when I add `style="fill: green"` to one of the path tags, it works, but this is done directly in the svg file. I would also like to do this for ALL path tags with a certain class name. So I'd like to change the color on the image to green for every path tag who's class is "Argentina" for example.

This is what my SVG looks like in HTML

```
    <object 
        id="color-change-svg" 
        data="../img/world.svg" 
        type="image/svg+xml"
    >
    </object>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's what you want. We'd need to know what's stopping you to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: [Access encapsulated component of <object> element in HTML for styling in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904416/access-encapsulated-component-of-object-element-in-html-for-styling-in-css/73906001#73906001)

Alternatively:

<s>I don't think the SVG XML code is inlined into the HTML if you embed it using . In order to change it using JavaScript, you will have to put the contents of the SVG file into your code.</s>

Try copying and pasting the contents of the SVG file into your HTML, and then you should be able to operate on it using JavaScript.

Comment: You can access and change object embedded content with javascript. I explain how to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904416/access-encapsulated-component-of-object-element-in-html-for-styling-in-css/73906001#73906001)

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed answer outlining the steps to manipulate svg elements may be useful to others who land on this question.

Assuming the `svg` image is embedded into the `html document`, svg `path` (and any other) tags can be manipulated in javascript in the same way as regular `html` tags are.

The process involves making a javascript reference to the `element`(s) represented by the tag. For tags with a unique `id` attribute, this might be achieved with the commonly used:

```
element = document.getElementById("tagID");
```

The unique element can then have its `attributes` manipulated using, for example to fill the path representing Brazil (`id="BR` in the svg markup) red:

```
const brazilPath = document.getElementById("BR");
brazilPath.setAttribute("fill","red");
```

Note the `.setAttribute` of an `element object` takes two quotted parameters, the `property name` (in this case "fill"), and the `value` to be assigned to the `property` (in this case a colour, red).

Where sets of elements are to be processed (such as the two paths needed to trace Argentina in the svg) an `html collection` (an array-like list of element references) can be made using any css selector that is common, and specific, to the elements to be targeted as the parameter of the `querySelectorAll` method:

```
const argentinaPaths = document.querySelectorAll("path.Argentina");
```

`path.Argentina` specifies "path elements of class Argentina". Including 'path' in the selector makes it more specific to the desired target (for example, the html page might have other elements with the class 'Argentina' which we want to ignore).

The html collection list returned by `.querySelectorAll` can be looped-though to have its `attributes` manipulated:

```
    for (let i=0; i<argentinaPaths.length; i++) {
      argentinaPaths[i].setAttribute("fill","green");
    }
```

These examples have been applied to the `svg` data in the question in the working snippet below. (The viewbox coordinates and dimensions have been changed from the original to home in on South America.):

```js
const brazilPath = document.getElementById("BR");
brazilPath.setAttribute("fill","red");

const argentinaPaths = document.querySelectorAll("path.Argentina");
for (let i=0; i<argentinaPaths.length; i++) {
  argentinaPaths[i].setAttribute("fill","green");
}
```

```css
div {
 width: 100%;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg baseprofile="tiny" fill="#ececec" height="857" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".2" version="1.2" viewbox="500 450 400 1300" width="2000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M1383 261.6l1.5 1.8-2.9 0.8-2.4 1.1-5.9 0.8-5.3 1.3-2.4 2.8 1.9 2.7 1.4 3.2-2 2.7 0.8 2.5-0.9 2.3-5.2-0.2 3.1 4.2-3.1 1.7-1.4 3.8 1.1 3.9-1.8 1.8-2.1-0.6-4 0.9-0.2 1.7-4.1 0-2.3 3.7 0.8 5.4-6.6 2.7-3.9-0.6-0.9 1.4-3.4-0.8-5.3 1-9.6-3.3 3.9-5.8-1.1-4.1-4.3-1.1-1.2-4.1-2.7-5.1 1.6-3.5-2.5-1 0.5-4.7 0.6-8 5.9 2.5 3.9-0.9 0.4-2.9 4-0.9 2.6-2-0.2-5.1 4.2-1.3 0.3-2.2 2.9 1.7 1.6 0.2 3 0 4.3 1.4 1.8 0.7 3.4-2 2.1 1.2 0.9-2.9 3.2 0.1 0.6-0.9-0.2-2.6 1.7-2.2 3.3 1.4-0.1 2 1.7 0.3 0.9 5.4 2.7 2.1 1.5-1.4 2.2-0.6 2.5-2.9 3.8 0.5 5.4 0z" id="AF" name="Afghanistan">
 </path>
 <path class="Angola" d="M 1121.2 572 1121.8 574 1121.1 577.1 1122 580.1 1121.1 582.5 1121.5 584.7 1109.8 584.6 1109 605.1 1112.6 610.3 1116.2 614.3 1105.8 616.9 1092.3 616 1088.5 613 1065.8 613.2 1065 613.7 1061.7 610.8 1058.1 610.6 1054.7 611.7 1052 612.9 1051.5 608.9 1052.4 603.2 1054.4 597.3 1054.7 594.6 1056.6 588.8 1058 586.2 1061.3 582 1063.2 579.1 1063.8 574.4 1063.5 570.7 1061.9 568.4 1060.4 564.5 1059.1 560.7 1059.4 559.3 1061.1 556.8 1059.5 550.6 1058.3 546.3 1055.5 542.2 1056.1 541 1058.4 540.1 1060.1 540.2 1062.1 539.5 1078.8 539.6 1080.1 544.3 1081.7 548.2 1083 550.3 1085.1 553.6 1088.9 553.1 1090.7 552.2 1093.8 553.1 1094.7 551.5 1096.2 547.8 1099.7 547.5 1100 546.4 1102.9 546.4 1102.4 548.7 1109.2 548.6 1109.3 552.7 1110.4 555.1 1109.5 559 1109.9 563 1111.7 565.4 1111.3 573 1112.7 572.4 1115.1 572.6 1118.6 571.6 1121.2 572 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Angola" d="M 1055.3 539 1053.8 534.2 1056.1 531.4 1057.8 530.3 1059.9 532.5 1057.9 533.9 1056.9 535.5 1056.7 538.3 1055.3 539 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1088 228l0.4 1.2 1.4-0.6 1.2 1.7 1.3 0.7 0.6 2.3-0.5 2.2 1 2.7 2.3 1.5 0.1 1.7-1.7 0.9-0.1 2.1-2.2 3.1-0.9-0.4-0.2-1.4-3.1-2.2-0.7-3 0.1-4.4 0.5-1.9-0.9-1-0.5-2.1 1.9-3.1z" id="AL" name="Albania">
 </path>
 <path d="M1296.2 336.7l1.3 5.1-2.8 0 0 4.2 1.1 0.9-2.4 1.3 0.2 2.6-1.3 2.6 0 2.6-1 1.4-16.9-3.2-2.7-6.6-0.3-1.4 0.9-0.4 0.4 1.8 4.2-1 4.6 0.2 3.4 0.2 3.3-4.4 3.7-4.1 3-4 1.3 2.2z" id="AE" name="United Arab Emirates">
 </path>
 <path class="Argentina" d="M 669.1 851.7 666.1 851.5 661.1 851.5 655.1 837.9 658.2 840.7 662.5 845.3 670.3 849 677.6 850.5 676.8 853.5 672.4 853.8 669.1 851.7 Z" >
 </path>
 <path class="Argentina" d="M 638.6 644.7 649.9 655.1 654.5 656.1 661.8 660.9 667.7 663.4 668.8 666.2 664.6 676 670.4 677.7 676.7 678.7 680.9 677.7 685.2 672.7 685.5 667.1 688.1 665.8 691.3 669.6 691.7 674.7 687.5 678.2 684.2 680.8 678.9 687.1 672.9 695.8 672.4 701 672 707.6 673.2 714 672.3 715.4 672.7 719.5 673 722.9 680.8 728.4 681 732.8 684.9 735.6 685.2 738.7 681.9 746.9 674.9 750.4 664.7 751.7 658.7 751 660.8 754.9 660.9 759.6 662.7 762.8 660.2 765.1 655.1 766 649.5 763.6 648 765.3 650.5 771.6 654.5 773.5 656.8 771.5 659.3 774.8 655.1 776.8 652.2 780.8 653.4 787.1 653.3 790.5 648.5 790.5 645.5 793.7 645.6 798.5 652.1 803.1 657.3 804.3 657.5 810 652.9 813.5 652.3 820.8 648.8 823.2 647.9 826.1 652.1 832.6 656.7 836.1 654.6 835.8 649.7 834.8 637.6 834 634.1 830.4 632.2 825.8 629.1 826.2 626.5 823.9 623.4 817.4 626.1 814.6 626.2 810.7 624.4 807.5 625.1 802.1 624 793.8 622.2 790.1 624 788.9 622.6 786.5 619.8 785.3 620.6 782.6 617.5 780.2 613.8 772.9 615.5 771.6 612.2 763.8 611.4 757.3 611.2 751.6 613.7 749.3 610.4 743 608.8 737.2 611.8 733 610.4 727.6 612 721.4 610.6 715.5 609 714.3 604.1 703.2 606.2 696.6 604.5 690.4 605.4 684.5 608 678.5 611.3 674.5 609.3 672 610.1 669.9 608.5 659.2 614.1 656.1 615.3 649.4 614.4 647.8 618.4 642 625.9 643.6 629.6 648.2 631.2 643 637.6 643.3 638.6 644.7 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1230.8 253l-1.8 0.2-2.8-3.7-0.2-1-2.3 0-1.9-1.7-1 0.1-2.4-1.8-4.2-1.6-0.1-3.1-1.3-2.2 7-1 1.4 1.6 2.2 1.1-0.7 1.6 3.2 2.2-1.1 2.1 2.6 1.7 2.5 1 0.9 4.5z" id="AM" name="Armenia">
 </path>
 <path class="Australia" d="M 1743 763.6 1746.7 765.8 1750 764.9 1754.9 763.7 1757.7 764.1 1753.2 771.7 1749.9 773.8 1745.9 779 1745.3 777.2 1738.7 781.6 1737.9 781.3 1734.9 781.1 1735.4 775.7 1737.4 771.5 1738 765.9 1740 763 1743 763.6 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Australia" d="M 1793.5 590.2 1794.7 595.2 1798.7 592.8 1800.1 595.5 1802.4 598 1801.3 600.9 1801.5 606.4 1801.7 609.6 1803 610.4 1803.4 615.9 1802.2 619.2 1803 623.5 1808.4 626.9 1811.6 629.9 1814.8 632.7 1813.7 634.3 1816 638.3 1816.5 645.3 1819.1 643.9 1820.6 646.6 1822.2 645.7 1821.5 652.5 1824.4 656.4 1826.3 658.8 1829.1 664 1829.1 669.2 1828.1 672.9 1826.3 676.8 1827 682.3 1824.5 688 1822.4 691 1818.6 696.7 1817.1 700.4 1814 705 1809 710.8 1803.5 714 1799.1 718.9 1795.8 722.1 1791.4 727.6 1787.7 730.8 1783.8 735.6 1780.7 740 1779.9 742.1 1775.6 744.3 1769.5 744.5 1763.2 747.2 1759.4 749.6 1754.6 752.4 1751.9 749.5 1749.3 748.4 1751.9 745.1 1748.4 746.3 1741.2 750.9 1737.6 749.2 1735.2 748.2 1732.4 747.7 1728.3 745.9 1727 741.9 1728.5 737.1 1728.9 733.8 1727.5 731.2 1722.8 730.5 1726 727.3 1726.9 722.6 1722.2 727 1716.9 728.2 1721.4 724.7 1723.9 721 1727.4 717.8 1729 713.1 1722.2 718.5 1717.9 720.7 1713.6 725.8 1710.6 723.2 1712.3 719.8 1710.9 715.1 1709.1 712.7 1710.7 711.2 1705.4 707.3 1701.6 707.2 1697.6 704 1687.7 704.6 1679.8 706.9 1672.9 709.1 1667.9 708.7 1660.9 712 1655.6 713.4 1653.3 716.8 1650.3 719.4 1645.6 719.6 1642 720.1 1637.8 719 1633.6 719.7 1629.8 720 1625.3 723.4 1623.8 723.1 1620.4 724.9 1617 726.9 1613.2 726.7 1609.7 726.7 1605.6 722.6 1603.2 721.4 1604.7 717.7 1607.6 716.8 1609.1 715.4 1609.7 713.1 1612 708.6 1612.7 704.8 1612 698.3 1612.2 694.6 1613.6 691 1612.7 686.8 1613 684.9 1611.3 682.3 1612 677.3 1610.1 672.2 1610 669.5 1611.8 672.3 1611.3 666.3 1613.6 668.2 1614.7 670.7 1615.3 667.4 1613.7 662.3 1613.6 660.3 1612.8 658.4 1614.1 654.7 1615.6 653.1 1616.9 649.9 1617 646.1 1620.1 641.5 1619.7 646.4 1622.8 642 1627.7 639.8 1630.9 637.1 1635.6 634.7 1638.2 634.2 1639.6 635 1644.4 632.6 1647.9 631.9 1649 630.5 1650.5 629.9 1653.6 630.1 1659.8 628.2 1663.3 625.3 1665.3 621.9 1669.2 618.7 1669.9 616.1 1670.6 612.6 1675.5 607.1 1676.9 612.7 1679.5 611.4 1678 608.4 1680.3 605.3 1682.5 606.7 1684 601.8 1687.5 598.6 1689.3 596.1 1692.2 595 1692.6 593.2 1694.9 593.9 1695.3 592.3 1697.9 591.4 1700.7 590.5 1704.4 593.5 1707 597.3 1710.5 597.3 1714 597.9 1713.3 594.4 1716.8 589.3 1719.5 587.6 1718.9 586 1721.8 582.3 1725.5 580 1728.2 580.8 1733.1 579.6 1733.4 576.3 1729.5 574.2 1732.6 573.3 1736.2 574.9 1738.9 577.5 1743.4 579.1 1745.1 578.5 1748.4 580.5 1751.9 578.6 1753.9 579.2 1755.4 577.9 1757.6 581.1 1755.6 584.6 1753.1 587.2 1751.2 587.4 1751.5 589.9 1749.3 593.1 1746.8 596.3 1747 598.1 1750.8 601.7 1754.8 603.7 1757.3 605.9 1760.6 609.7 1762.2 609.7 1764.8 611.4 1765.3 613.4 1770.2 615.5 1774.3 613.3 1776.1 609.9 1777.8 607 1779.1 603.5 1781.7 598.4 1781.5 595.3 1782.2 593.4 1782.1 589.8 1783.5 584.9 1784.8 583.6 1784.2 581.5 1786 578.1 1787.5 574.6 1787.9 572.7 1790.2 570.3 1791.5 573.5 1791.4 577.5 1792.7 578.3 1792.6 581 1794.2 584.2 1794.1 587.9 1793.5 590.2 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1070.6 190.8l-0.3 0.8 0.7 2.1-0.2 2.6-2.8 0 1.1 1.4-1.3 4-0.9 1.1-4.4 0.1-2.4 1.5-4.2-0.5-7.3-1.7-1.3-2.1-4.9 1.1-0.5 1.2-3.1-0.9-2.6-0.2-2.3-1.2 0.7-1.5-0.2-1.1 1.4-0.3 2.7 1.7 0.6-1.7 4.4 0.3 3.5-1.1 2.4 0.2 1.7 1.3 0.4-1.1-1-4.1 1.7-0.8 1.6-2.9 3.8 2.1 2.6-2.6 1.7-0.5 4 1.9 2.3-0.3 2.4 1.2z" id="AT" name="Austria">
 </path>
 <path class="Azerbaijan" d="M 1229 253.2 1225.2 252.3 1222 249.4 1220.8 246.9 1221.8 246.8 1223.7 248.5 1226 248.5 1226.2 249.5 1229 253.2 Z">
 </path>
 <path class="Azerbaijan" d="M 1235.3 236.2 1237.8 233.6 1241.3 236.9 1244.9 241.5 1247.4 241.8 1249.3 243.5 1245.1 244 1245.2 249 1244.8 251.2 1243.1 252.7 1243.9 255.8 1242.6 256.2 1238.7 252.8 1239.9 249.7 1238 247.8 1236.1 248.3 1230.8 253 1229.9 248.5 1227.4 247.5 1224.8 245.8 1225.9 243.7 1222.7 241.5 1223.4 239.9 1221.2 238.8 1219.8 237.2 1220.9 236.1 1225.1 238 1228 238.3 1228.6 237.6 1225.3 234.1 1226.5 233.3 1228 233.5 1232.3 237.3 1234.7 237.8 1235.3 236.2 Z">
 </path>
 <path d="M1154.9 530.4l-0.6 0.1 0-0.3-2-6.1-0.01-0.06-0.09-1.04-1.4-2.9 3.5 0.5 1.7-3.7 3.1 0.4 0.3 2.5 1.2 1.5 0 2.1-1.4 1.3-2.3 3.4-2 2.3z" id="BI" name="Burundi">
 </path>
 <path d="M1016.5 177.1l-0.4 4.2-1.3 0.2-0.4 3.5-4.4-2.9-2.5 0.5-3.5-2.9-2.4-2.5-2.2-0.1-0.8-2.2 3.9-1.2 3.6 0.5 4.5-1.3 3.1 2.7 2.8 1.5z" id="BE" name="Belgium">
 </path>
 <path d="M1006.7 427l-0.2 2.1 1.3 3.8-1.1 2.6 0.6 1.7-2.8 4-1.7 2-1.1 4 0.2 4.1-0.3 10.3-4.7 0.8-1.4-4.4 0.3-14.8-1.2-1.3-0.2-3.2-2-2.2-1.7-1.9 0.7-3.4 2-0.7 1.1-2.8 2.8-0.6 1.2-1.9 1.9-1.9 2 0 4.3 3.7z" id="BJ" name="Benin">
 </path>
 <path d="M988.5 406l-0.5 3.1 0.8 2.9 3.1 4.2 0.2 3.1 6.5 1.5-0.1 4.4-1.2 1.9-2.8 0.6-1.1 2.8-2 0.7-4.9-0.1-2.6-0.5-1.8 1-2.5-0.5-9.8 0.3-0.2 3.7 0.8 4.8-3.9-1.6-2.6 0.2-2 1.6-2.5-1.3-1-2.2-2.5-1.4-0.4-3.7 1.6-2.7-0.2-2.2 4.5-5.3 0.9-4.4 1.5-1.6 2.7 0.9 2.4-1.3 0.8-1.7 4.3-2.8 1.1-2 5.3-2.7 3.1-0.9 1.4 1.2 3.6 0z" id="BF" name="Burkina Faso">
 </path>
 <path d="M1500.6 360.3l0.6 4.6-2.1-1 1.1 5.2-2.1-3.3-0.8-3.3-1.5-3.1-2.8-3.7-5.2-0.3 0.9 2.7-1.2 3.5-2.6-1.3-0.6 1.2-1.7-0.7-2.2-0.6-1.6-5.3-2.6-4.8 0.3-3.9-3.7-1.7 0.9-2.3 3-2.4-4.6-3.4 1.2-4.4 4.9 2.8 2.7 0.3 1.2 4.5 5.4 0.9 5.1-0.1 3.4 1.1-1.6 5.4-2.4 0.4-1.2 3.6 3.6 3.4 0.3-4.2 1.5 0 4.4 10.2z" id="BD" name="Bangladesh">
 </path>
 <path d="M1132.6 221.6l-2.3 2.6-1.3 4.5 2.1 3.6-4.6-0.8-5 2 0.3 3.2-4.6 0.6-3.9-2.3-4 1.8-3.8-0.2-0.8-4.2-2.8-2.1 0.7-0.8-0.6-0.8 0.6-2 1.8-2-2.8-2.7-0.7-2.4 1.1-1.4 1.8 2.6 1.9-0.4 4 0.9 7.6 0.4 2.3-1.6 5.9-1.5 4 2.3 3.1 0.7z" id="BG" name="Bulgaria">
 </path>
 <path d="M1083 214.3l1.9-0.1-1.1 2.8 2.7 2.5-0.5 2.9-1.1 0.3-0.9 0.6-1.6 1.5-0.4 3.5-4.8-2.4-2.1-2.7-2.1-1.4-2.5-2.4-1.3-1.9-2.7-3 0.8-2.6 2 1.5 1-1.4 2.3-0.1 4.5 1.1 3.5-0.1 2.4 1.4z" id="BA" name="Bosnia and Herzegovina">
 </path>
 <path d="M1141.6 162.7l-3.9-0.2-0.8 0.6 1.5 2 2 4-4.1 0.3-1.3 1.4 0.3 3.1-2.1-0.6-4.3 0.3-1.5-1.5-1.7 1.1-1.9-0.9-3.9-0.1-5.7-1.5-4.9-0.5-3.8 0.2-2.4 1.6-2.3 0.3-0.5-2.8-1.9-2.8 2.8-1.3-0.4-2.4-1.7-2.3-0.6-2.7 4.7 0 4.8-2.3 0.5-3.4 3.6-2-1-2.7 2.7-1 4.6-2.3 5.3 1.5 0.9 1.5 2.4-0.7 4.8 1.4 1.1 2.9-0.7 1.6 3.8 4 2.1 1.1 0 1.1 3.4 1.1 1.7 1.6-1.6 1.3z" id="BY" name="Belarus">
 </path>
 <path d="M487.8 399.8l-1.7 0 1.3-7.2 0.7-5.1 0.1-1 0.7-0.3 0.9 0.8 2.5-3.9 1.1-0.1-0.1 1 1 0-0.3 1.8-1.3 2.7 0.4 1-0.9 2.3 0.3 0.6-1 3.3-1.3 1.7-1.1 0.2-1.3 2.2z" id="BZ" name="Belize">
 </path>
 <path d="M662.5 631.4l-0.3-2-5.4-3.3-5.2-0.1-9.6 1.9-2.1 5.6 0.2 3.5-1.5 7.7-1-1.4-6.4-0.3-1.6 5.2-3.7-4.6-7.5-1.6-4 5.8-3.9 0.9-3.1-8.9-3.7-7.2 1.1-6.2-3.2-2.7-1.2-4.6-3.2-4.4 2.9-6.9-2.9-5.4 1.1-2.2-1.2-2.4 1.9-3.2-0.3-5.4 0-4.6 1.1-2.1-5.5-10.4 4.2 0.6 2.9-0.2 1.1-1.9 4.8-2.6 2.9-2.4 7.3-1.1-0.4 4.8 0.9 2.5-0.3 4.3 6.5 5.7 6.4 1.1 2.3 2.4 3.9 1.3 2.5 1.8 3.5 0 3.4 1.9 0.5 3.7 1.2 1.9 0.3 2.7-1.7 0.1 2.8 7.5 10.7 0.3-0.5 3.7 0.8 2.5 3.2 1.8 1.7 4-0.6 5.1-1.3 2.8 0.8 3.6-1.6 1.4z" id="BO" name="Bolivia">
 </path>
 <path d="M665.8 489.6l3.1 0.6 0.6-1.4-1-1.2 0.6-1.9 2.3 0.6 2.7-0.7 3.2 1.4 2.5 1.3 1.7-1.7 1.3 0.2 0.8 1.8 2.7-0.4 2.2-2.5 1.8-4.7 3.4-5.9 2-0.3 1.3 3.6 3 11.2 3.1 1.1 0.1 4.4-4.3 5.3 1.7 1.9 10.1 1 0.2 6.5 4.3-4.2 7.1 2.3 9.5 3.9 2.8 3.7-0.9 3.6 6.6-2 11 3.4 8.5-0.2 8.4 5.3 7.4 7.2 4.4 1.8 4.8 0.3 2.1 2 2 8.2 1.1 3.9-2.1 10.6-2.7 4.2-7.7 8.9-3.4 7.3-4 5.5-1.4 0.2-1.3 4.7 0.9 12-1.1 9.9-0.3 4.2-1.6 2.6-0.5 8.6-5.2 8.3-0.5 6.7-4.3 2.7-1.1 3.9-6 0-8.5 2.4-3.7 2.9-6 1.9-6.1 5.1-4.1 6.4-0.3 4.8 1.3 3.5-0.3 6.5-0.8 3.1-3.4 3.6-4.5 11.3-4 5-3.2 3.1-1.5 6.1-2.9 3.6-2.1-3.6 1.8-3.1-3.8-4.3-4.8-3.6-6.3-4.1-1.9 0.2-6.3-5-3.4 0.7 6-8.7 5.3-6.3 3.3-2.6 4.2-3.5-0.4-5.1-3.2-3.8-2.6 1.3 0.7-3.7 0.3-3.8-0.3-3.6-2.1-1.1-2 1-2.1-0.3-0.8-2.4-1.1-5.9-1.2-1.9-3.9-1.8-2.2 1.3-5.9-1.3-0.4-8.7-2-3.5 1.6-1.4-0.8-3.6 1.3-2.8 0.6-5.1-1.7-4-3.2-1.8-0.8-2.5 0.5-3.7-10.7-0.3-2.8-7.5 1.7-0.1-0.3-2.7-1.2-1.9-0.5-3.7-3.4-1.9-3.5 0-2.5-1.8-3.9-1.3-2.3-2.4-6.4-1.1-6.5-5.7 0.3-4.3-0.9-2.5 0.4-4.8-7.3 1.1-2.9 2.4-4.8 2.6-1.1 1.9-2.9 0.2-4.2-0.6-3.2 1.1-2.6-0.7-0.1-9.7-4.4 3.7-5-0.1-2.3-3.5-3.8-0.3 1-2.8-3.3-3.9-2.6-5.8 1.5-1.1-0.2-2.8 3.4-1.8-0.7-3.5 1.4-2.2 0.3-3 6.3-4.4 4.6-1.2 0.8-1 5.1 0.3 2.2-17.6 0.1-2.8-0.9-3.6-2.6-2.4 0.1-4.7 3.2-1 1.1 0.7 0.2-2.5-3.3-0.7 0-4 11 0.2 1.9-2.3 1.6 2.1 1 3.8 1.1-0.8 3.1 3.4 4.4-0.4 1.1-2 4.2-1.5 2.4-1.1 0.7-2.7 4.1-1.8-0.3-1.4-4.8-0.5-0.7-4.1 0.3-4.3-2.5-1.6 1.1-0.6 4.1 0.8 4.5 1.6 1.7-1.5 4.1-1 6.4-2.4 2.1-2.5-0.7-1.8 3-0.2 1.2 1.4-0.8 2.9 2 0.9 1.2 3-1.6 2.3-1 5.4 1.4 3.3 0.3 3 3.5 3 2.8 0.3 0.6-1.3 1.8-0.3 2.6-1.1 1.8-1.7 3.2 0.6 1.3-0.3z" id="BR" name="Brazil">
 </path>
 <path d="M1633.1 472.8l2.2-2.4 4.6-3.6-0.1 3.2-0.1 4.1-2.7-0.2-1.1 2.2-2.8-3.3z" id="BN" name="Brunei Darussalam">
 </path>
 </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup, helped a ton. Would you happen to know how to pass in a class name with more than one word? Ex. "United States" (like the path.Argentina example)

Comment: An element that had the attribute `class="United States"` actually has two classes assigned to it (as class names cannot have spaces). Both class "United" and class "States" are applied to it. Thus, the selector parameter would be `path.United.States` to select `path` elements having both the class `.United` and the class `.States`. There is a useful list of combined class selectors in this SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes