# Changing color of svg, specifically loaded with css "content" using currentcolor

Tags: html, css, svg

Im having trouble changing the color of a svg that is loaded usign "content: url("svg-path")". The svg is using currentcolor for fill, and is changing color fine if the svg is loaded directly in the html.
The two [Svg images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeCHN.png) should be the same color.

The Svg in question

```
<svg
    fill="currentcolor"
    viewBox="0 0 200 200"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs/>
  <g
  fill="currentcolor">
    <circle       
      id="path846"
      cx="105.50797"
      cy="128.38446"
      r="45.161354" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I have the current test setup to display my issue

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #6592d5;
  }
  .test::before {
    content: url("Path to svg file");
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <svg
           fill="currentcolor"
           viewBox="0 0 200 200"
           version="1.1"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs/>
          <g
             fill="currentcolor">
            <circle       
               id="path846"
               cx="105.50797"
               cy="128.38446"
               r="45.161354" />
          </g>
        </svg>

      <span class="test">  
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I prob misunderstood what you mean. there are many ways you can change color of an svg either you can change the svg itself by opening it into a notepad(any app you can open it) then save it or you can call it as an image then change the color from there. heres a link that might help you understand more about it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element

Comment: The problem is, that I would like for it to be changed using css, so I can change the color of a svg, to match a theme color. This would not be possible if I would have to change it in the svg file. And calling it in the html is a last resort, since i would be reusing the svg many times.