# Filter SVG to target color

Tags: css, svg, filter, inline-svg

I want to filter a SVG graphic embedded in CSS to a specific color.

To be specific, I want to use the CSS `filter: hue-rotate(),...` and not manipulate the SVG (only the fill, or stroke prop).

The HSL values for the color are as follows:

```css
color: hsl(268deg, 50%, 50%);
```

The SVG graphic has `stroke="red"`, so in HSL:

```css
hsl(0, 100%, 50%)
```

With the filter:

```css
filter: hue-rotate(268deg) saturate(50%) brightness(100%);
```

the icon becomes this:

```css
hsl(261, 62%, 38%)
```

With some effort, I found suitable filter values:

```css
filter: hue-rotate(275deg) saturate(0.325) brightness(1.63);
```

But these only fit to the used target color.

Is there a way, in CSS, to create a universal filter that always makes the correct target color out of a defined stroke color?

### Example

and as a codepen: https://codepen.io/koljal/pen/MWBGGLg

```css
:root {
  --link-color: hsl(268deg, 50%, 50%);
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin-inline: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  color: var(--link-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1em' height='1em' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='m20 4l-2 14.5l-6 2l-6-2L4 4zM8.5 8h7L11 12h4l-.5 3.5l-2.5.75l-2.5-.75l-.1-.5'/></svg>");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.simple {
  filter: hue-rotate(268deg) saturate(50%) brightness(100%);
}

.custom {
  filter: hue-rotate(275deg) saturate(0.325) brightness(1.63);
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the Target color</h1>

<code>
  hsl(268deg,50%,50%)
</code>

<h2>SVG icon as CSS-inlne background-image</h2>
<code>
  <pre>
  fill="red"
  aka: hsl(0, 100%, 50%)
 </pre>
</code>
<div class="icon"></div>

<h2>simple filter on SVG</h2>
<code>
  <pre>
filter: hue-rotate(268deg) saturate(50%) brightness(100%);
 </pre>
</code>
<div class="icon simple"></div>
Result:
<code>
  <pre>
hsl(261, 62%, 38%)
 </pre>
</code>
<h2>custom filter</h2>
<code>
  <pre>
filter: hue-rotate(275deg) saturate(0.325) brightness(1.63);
 </pre>
</code>
<div class="icon custom"></div>
Result:
<code>
  <pre>
hsl(268, 50%, 50%)
 </pre>
</code>
```

Comment: Is your reason for doing this to change the colour of the SVG?

Comment: Yes, to have the same color in the SVG stroke like in the links, or headings for example. Including hover effect 

Comment: You can't do this in css alone, since the **calculation is quite tricky** and also an approximation. See this [generator codepen](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp). I'd rather recommend switching to another embedding concept (e.g. `<use>` or using a css mask image) as described here ["How can I change the color of an 'svg' element?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element)