# How can I make an element overflow the grid width, without affecting grid columns sizes?

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid, overlap

Please see the following snippet.

I've got a basic grid layout with overlapping cells (but in this case the overlapping thing doesn't matter). I'd like to insert a `50vw` element on `col-2`, which should start from the center of the screen (current col-2 starting point) and go to the end of the screen, overflowing the cell itself.

If I try to do it, it will not work. Instead, it will modify all the cells current sizes.
How can I avoid it?

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  //grid-template-columns: 6fr 2fr 4fr;
  grid-template-columns: 6fr 2fr minmax(0, 4fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  min-width: 0;

  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}

.column{
  min-height: 100px;
}

.col-1{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 9;

  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, .5);

  z-index: 10;
}

.col-2{
  grid-column-start: 7;
  grid-column-end: 13;

  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, .5);
}

.inner{
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column col-1">col 1</div>
  <div class="column col-2">
    col 2<br>
    <!-- <div class="inner">inner</div> (should be 50vw) -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: start by removing the comma inside your templates, we use only space there

Comment: and when using 6fr it doesn't mean 6 columns but only 1 column so you have 3 columns but using 13 as column-end

Comment: It's a 12 cols grid. It's a way to retain relative widths. Anyway, that's not the point of my question.

Comment: it's *the* point of your question. If you correctly define 12 cols then your code will work fine. Actually you are defining 3 columns and using 12 columns so the browser will logically and automatically set the width of the column based on their content since your are not defining their width

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Great, thank you, it works: would you like to add a real answer or do you prefer I'll do it for you?

Comment: `//` is [not a valid comment character sequence in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments) (the browser will most likely terminate processing the CSS from that point on). Only the C style `/* */` is valid. From the source (my emphasis): *"The `/* */` comment syntax is used for both single and multiline comments. There is* ***no other way*** *to specify comments in external style sheets."*

Comment: See also *[Why do /**/ comments work in stylesheets but // comments don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479351/why-do-comments-work-in-stylesheets-but-comments-dont)*

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0;
}
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
  min-width: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}

.column{
  min-height: 100px;
}

.col-1{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, .5);
  
  z-index: 10;
}

.col-2{
  grid-column-start: 7;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, .5);
}

.inner{
  width: 50vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column col-1">col 1</div>
  <div class="column col-2">
    <div class="inner">inner</div>
    col 2
  </div>
</div>
```